# Signing commit with OpenPGP subkey fails

Tags: git, gnupg

I would like to use one of my GPS (2) subkeys for signing commits/tags in Git
I.e., my freshly created RSA4096 signing-only key with the long ID B0##...

```
sec#  ed25519/9F############## 2016-01-07 [expires: 2023-01-05]
  Key fingerprint = FC08 HEX HEX HEX 
uid                 [ultimate] MY NAME <MY.NAME@foo bar>
ssb   rsa4096/C9############## 2016-01-07 [expires: 2022-01-05]
ssb   ed25519/C6############## 2016-01-07 [expires: 2022-01-05]
ssb   rsa4096/B0############## 2016-01-13 [expires: 2022-01-11]
```

Where I am working on a keyring with the master key removed (backuped away) as 'better key policy'

So, I tried to set up the signing key for Git

```
[user]
    ...
    signingkey = B0##############
```

However, committing & signing fails with

```
> git commit -S  -m "test commit"
gpg: skipped "B0##############": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Where a gpg-agent up and running.

My first guess was, that Git does not understand the long key notation and tried the short one instead

```
> gpg2 --list-secret-keys  --keyid-format short
...
ssb   rsa4096/DB###### 2016-01-13 [expires: 2022-01-11]

> ~/.gitconfig
[user]
   ...
   signingkey = DB######
```

But which also failed

```
> git commit -S  -m "test commit short"
gpg: skipped "DB######": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

So, I wonder what breaks here and if maybe Git only would work with a master key for signing but does not understand the use of subkeys (or if I have screwed up myself somewhere)?

Comment: Try setting `gpg2` as `gpg.program`. Since you use `gpg2` for running GnuPG 2.0, `gpg` will be GnuPG 1 without any support for elliptic curves. Be aware that currently, a vast majority will _not_ be able to handle your signatures, as your primary key is an elliptic curve key.

Comment: Yeay! That did the trick!
I am aware, that EC25519 ist not very standard conform (yet) - it was a bit of an exercise to use it but maybe was not the best decision on the short-term ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Git uses `gpg` by default, which is GnuPG 1 on most systems and does not support elliptic curve cryptography. As your primary key is an elliptic curve key, GnuPG 1 cannot use the key at all. You will be able to observe the same when trying to use the key with GnuPG (`gpg --default-key key-id --sign`).

Configure Git to use `gpg2` instead, which is required to be at least GnuPG 2.1 (which you have, as you can use the elliptic curves key):

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg2
```

Comment: Thanks. Using gpg2 also solved my issue with RSA keys. git was refusing to commit because the master private key wasn't present.

Comment: This is an issue when using GnuPG 2.1 or newer, which moved private keys into the public keyring. GnuPG prior (1.4, 2.0) will not find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Git now uses `gpg2` by default, but Git 2.25 (Q1 2020) fixes another source of failure.

The code to parse GPG output used to assume incorrectly that the finterprint for the primary key would always be present for a valid signature, which has been corrected.

See [commit 67a6ea6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67a6ea63008bcee32a239934ad29eb5c5a554509) (22 Nov 2019), and [commit 392b862](https://github.com/git/git/commit/392b862e9aea69acf43532527e27644c97e3ea56) (21 Nov 2019) by [Hans Jerry Illikainen (`illikainen`)](https://github.com/illikainen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f06dff7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f06dff7b7c1cfd273f2e23cfee547c0f05f76e31), 05 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`gpg-interface`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67a6ea63008bcee32a239934ad29eb5c5a554509): limit search for primary key fingerprint
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Hans Jerry Illikainen</sup>
>
> The `VALIDSIG` status line from GnuPG with `--status-fd` is documented to have 9 required and 1 optional fields.
>
> The final, and optional, field is used to specify the fingerprint of the primary key that made the signature in case it was made by a subkey.
>
> However, this field is only available for OpenPGP signatures; not for CMS/X.509.
>
> If the `VALIDSIG` status line does not have the optional 10th field, the current code will continue reading onto the next status line.
>
> And this is the case for non-OpenPGP signatures.
>
> The consequence is that a subsequent status line may be considered as the "primary key" for signatures that does not have an actual primary key.
>
> Limit the search of these 9 or 10 fields to the single line to avoid this problem.
>
> If the 10th field is missing, report that there is no primary key fingerprint.
>
> The **[documentation](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blame/f59455d054a79068ebf480cd28f02993c1facf3b/doc/DETAILS#L482)** says:
>
> > ```
> > VALIDSIG <args>
> > ```
> >
> > The args are:
> >
> > - `<fingerprint_in_hex>`
> > - `<sig_creation_date>`
> > - `<sig-timestamp>`
> > - `<expire-timestamp>`
> > - `<sig-version>`
> > - `<reserved>`
> > - `<pubkey-algo>`
> > - `<hash-algo>`
> > - `<sig-class>`
> > - [ `<primary-key-fpr>` ]
> >
> > This status indicates that the signature is cryptographically valid.
> >     [...] `PRIMARY-KEY-FPR` is the fingerprint of the primary key or identical to the first argument.
> >
> > The `primary-key-fpr` parameter is used for OpenPGP and not available for CMS signatures.  [...]