# gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object [Git 2.10.0]

Tags: git, github, gpg-signature

I followed few articles over the [pretty](https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log) attributes on [Git 2.10](https://github.com/blog/2242-git-2-10-has-been-released) release note. Going through which upgraded the git to 2.10.0 and made changes to global `.gitconfig` resulting as follows -

```
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
    required = true
[user]
    name = xyz
    email = abc.def@gmail.com
    signingkey = AAAAAAA
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/xyz/.gitignore_global
    editor = 'subl' --wait
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = 
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
[alias]
    lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
[color "diff"]
    old = red strike
    new = green italic
```

But now that I try to sign my commits using

```
git commit -a -S -m "message"
```

I get to see the following error -

> You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
>
> user: "XYZ (Digitally Signed) "
>
> 2048-bit RSA key, ID AAAAAAAA, created 2016-07-01
>
> error: gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit
>   object

***Note*** - I can still commit changes using `git commit -a -m "message"`

***Is there a way to overcome the same? Or any change required in `gpg` configs to get along with the upgradation of git?***

---

***Update 1***

Also seeking further usefulness, following [Is there a way to "autosign" commits in Git with a GPG key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161198/is-there-a-way-to-autosign-commits-in-git-with-a-gpg-key). I've already configured the key using

```
git config --global user.signingkey ED5CDE14(with my key) 
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
```

and quite obviously getting the same error anyway.

Comment: I face similar issue. I uninstalled Git 2.8 (git-scm) on Windows. And installed 2.10. Now I get `gpg failed to sign the data` every time I use `-S`. In 2.8, I can sign a commit without problem. I don't know what happen.

Comment: Adding `user.signingkey` fixed my issue, strangely enough.

Comment: Possible duplicates:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052538/git-error-gpg-failed-to-sign-data and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502146/git-gpg-onto-mac-osx-error-gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data

Comment: An irony, I'd changed my machine to set up things afresh and ended up looking for my own question and none of the suggested solution looks clean enough to me to just get started simply.

Comment: Try `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` [as discussed here](https://superuser.com/a/1150399)

Comment: For me fix was: git config `user.name` was != name used when creating PGP key

Comment: Make sure that `git config --get-all user.name` and `git config --get-all user.email` are same as key used for signing, which can be checked via `gpg -K --keyid-format SHORT`

Comment: In my case, I use GPG Keychain on macOS. I opened it up and my primary key had expired a couple days ago. It prompted me to extend it. I did that and retried the commit and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: In my case, I use GPG Keychain on macOS, and `~/.gnupg` is a symbolic link to my streaming Google Drive (`/Volumes/Google Drive/...`). Switching Google Drive to mirroring mode fixed it. The clue was `gpg-agent --daemon` → `error binding socket to '/Users/cunnie/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': Operation not supported`

Comment: The irony is that the question asked around 6 years ago (2016), is still valid & applicable in 2022.

Comment: `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` worked for me on Ventura. Thanks

Comment: also ensure your gpg key has not expired recently

Answer (score 966, accepted):

I ran into this issue with macOS.

#### Original answer:

It seems like a gpg update (of brew) changed to location of `gpg` to `gpg1`, you can change the binary where git looks up the gpg:

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg1
```

If you don't have gpg1: `brew install gpg1`.

#### Updated answer:

It looks like gpg1 is being deprecated/["gently nudged out of usage"](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/708#issuecomment-239625115), so you probably should actually update to gpg2, unfortunately this involves quite a few more steps/a bit of time:

```
brew upgrade gnupg  # This has a make step which takes a while
brew link --overwrite gnupg
brew install pinentry-mac
echo "pinentry-program $(brew --prefix)/bin/pinentry-mac" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
killall gpg-agent
```

The first part installs gpg2, and latter is [a hack required to use it](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/14737#issuecomment-309547412). For troubleshooting, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41054093/1240268) (though that is about linux not brew), it suggests a good test:

```
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign  # on linux it's gpg2 but brew stays as gpg
```

If this test is successful (no error/output includes PGP signature), you have successfully updated to the latest gpg version.

You should now be able to use git signing again!
It's worth noting you'll need to have:

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg  # perhaps you had this already? On linux maybe gpg2
git config --global commit.gpgsign true  # if you want to sign every commit
```

Note: After you've run a signed commit, you can verify it signed with:

```
git log --show-signature -1
```

which will include gpg info for the last commit.

Comment: Setting gpg.program to /usr/local/bin/gpg (no "1") fixed it for me.

Comment: @nullpointer apologies, only just saw the second comment. Looks like this is discussed [on github](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/708#issuecomment-239627010), the long and short of it seems to be: it was in the caveats, no-one reads the caveats!

Comment: It seems an update of `gnupg2` with `brew` messed with symlinks thus `gpg` was removed, I had fix links using `brew link --overwrite gnupg2`.

Comment: `brew install gpg1` to install gpg1

Comment: @Dorian why did you delete the reference to the medium blog post?

Comment: hm... doesn't work. still gives my error with signing in xcode.

Comment: This answer from 2016 should be upgraded. It is better now to use `git config --global gpg.program gpg` , which links just fine to gpg2

Comment: @DrBeco isn't that the original location/behavior? I still have the same issue on osx (I think I have updated my brew fairly recently), `gpg1` is the still exported executable.

Comment: Hum... Maybe it is a OSX thing. Mine (debian) is working fine (not before I hit my head in many bricks). Well, let it as it is, or if in the future you come up with some definite solution, it is always better to use the latest versions of gpg (or any software btw).

Comment: @DrBeco ah, interesting, so [gpg1 is being "gently nudged out of usage"](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/708#issuecomment-239625115), I will look into this and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: It's working for me, and I use the gpg2, now.

```git config --global gpg.program gpg2```

Comment: For me, all I had to do was `brew resintall pinentry-mac` (and `killall gpg-agent` and do a test sign with `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign`), because somehow it could not do it's job.

Comment: `killall gpg-agent && gpg-agent --daemon --use-standard-socket --pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry` finally fixed it for me

Comment: Im on mac and I had to do `echo no-tty >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` to fix this

Comment: I just want to say that it is only working if used system /usr/bin/git and not works with git installed via brew

Comment: First make sure you've imported your gpg key to your newly installed machine.

Comment: With the `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign` I'm getting `gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: It only worked with me when i used the short ID 
`git config --global user.signingkey <short Key ID>`  .

Comment: I also issued some problems (MacOS) after all operations. If so, plz refer this comment https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues/issues/2798

Comment: I only did `killall gpg-agent` and the problem was gone. Thanks @DanBechard

Comment: @DanBechard how to make this survive a reboot?

Comment: @blackjacx it survives reboot for me, but you could schedule a cron job to run at startup.

Comment: As of Catalina (11.1) the homebrew formula for `gpg` is identical to `gpg2`. I suspect `gpg2` is being retained for backwards compatibility. You might want to update your answer

Comment: I solved it. Instructions are right overall. The problem is in the line `echo "pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` — before blindly copy-pasting, check yourself, where is executable "`pinentry-mac`" located. It's done via `which`: `which pinentry-mac`. On my M1 mac mini, it's `/opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-mac`! So, edit that `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, for example using sublime text: `subl ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and edit accordingly, like in my case: `pinentry-program /opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-mac`. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Doesn't work. Now I'm being prompted for a pin. I've never had a pin, and I've never needed to enter anything like a pin to commit before, so I still can't commit. You never explain why `pinentry` is required at all.

Comment: Adding to the fun here. I had to add the email of the parent key (my signing key is a subkey) as opposed to using the keygrip which is how I have it set-up on Linux.

Comment: When I remove `~/.gnupg` and configure a new key it's solved for me.

Comment: In MacOs the one that worked for me was `git config --global gpg.program gpg2`

Comment: Updated answer worked exactly as expected for me. Thank you!

Comment: I already had GPG on my Windows PC, and `gpg --list-keys` would successfully list my key **in Git Bash* (not in the standard Windows Command Line), however, GitHub Desktop wasn't working for me. The solution was to add Git's GPG binary to my PATH variable. So I added `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to the PATH, and GitHub Desktop began working. If you have Git installed on your PC, you likely already have GPG installed at: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe`.

Answer (score 765):

If gnupg2 and gpg-agent 2.x are used, be sure to set the environment variable `GPG_TTY`.

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

See [GPG’s documentation about common problems](https://www.gnupg.org/(it)/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Common-Problems.html).

Comment: If using fish, put `set -x GPG_TTY (tty)` on your profile.

Comment: @StuartCardall What is the point of the chown command? Typically it will have already been assigned to you by a system process, when you logged in or created the pseudo-tty. If it's owned by someone else and you're not root, it will fail. If the group is something else, it probably doesn't matter, and users will typically not be in group tty.

Comment: @poolie - it matters if you `su` to `root` on a remote server

Comment: I added the variable to `~/.zshrc` and I can make commits again, now that it connects correctly to the terminal.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: This is also in the GitHub instructions: https://help.github.com/articles/telling-git-about-your-gpg-key/

Comment: How to remember this export, so I don't need to execute this command every time?

Comment: This has had me chasing my tail for weeks! Sometimes it works, others it doesn't! This was the key to making it work reliably! Thank you!

Comment: I ran this command and it still doesn't work, I'm using Bash and GPG 2.2.4.

Comment: This is what I needed for WSL2.

Comment: This worked for me with `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.23` installed using `brew install gpg`.

Comment: `zsh` users with Powerlevel10k with Instant Prompt enabled beware, you might end up with a `not a tty` value: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608921/5095. A quick workaround is to just use a much faster and safer (in the context of Zsh): `export GPG_TTY=$TTY`.

Comment: JFI: Please check if the terminal has enough space to display passphrase input. I had the same issue where in VSCode I made the terminal smaller and then committing would fail with the same error because passphrase input was not able to be displayed.

Comment: This is the million-dollar answer. Worked for me from 2022 through 2024 on current versions of Ubuntu, Debian, and Arch.

Answer (score 489):

`GIT_TRACE=1` shows what git is actually doing:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -m "example commit message"
20:52:58.902766 git.c:328               trace: built-in: git 'commit' '-vvv' '-m' 'example commit message'
20:52:58.918467 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'gpg' '--status-fd=2' '-bsau' '23810377252EF4C2'
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Now run the failing command manually:

```
$ echo "dummy" | gpg -bsau 23810377252EF4C2
gpg: skipped "23810377252EF4C2": Unusable secret key
gpg: signing failed: Unusable secret key
```

Turns out that my key was expired, and `git` was not to blame.

Comment: This actually helped me solve my own problem, and it's a solution for every type of problem with this status message. +1

Comment: Thanks for the debugging walk through. My key was expired as well.

Comment: Thanks!  This led me to my problem. Strangely enough my local `.git/config` had a `name` specified in one project that did not match my signing email.  That was enough to reject it.

Comment: Well, executing `gpg -bsau <key>` on my machine doesn't execute anything. Is this suppose to take too long to execute? Or does that mean the key is fine to be used? @VonC any insights?

Comment: @nullpointer It depends on your version of Git and your PATH. Try the same command with a simplified PATH (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49248983/6309), for testing.

Comment: I get `secret key not available`

Comment: If your key was expired, you can renew it following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728576/2635190

Comment: I had a similar problem to @kross. My git is configured with `Aaron Meurer <asmeurer@gmail.com>` but somehow my gpg key got generated with `Aaron S. Meurer <asmeurer@gmail.com>`. Adding `Aaron Meurer <asmeurer@gmail.com>` to my gpg key and setting it as the primary fixed the problem.

Comment: I get `gpgsm: can't sign using '...': No public key`. Any ideas please?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I was able to check my secret has not been imported properly

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Better to know what's going on than to try a million different possible solutions blindly

Comment: I also got this exact error but my keys are not expired. Turns out I had to put my GPG key into github as well

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it for me. My gpg agent was a point release behind running gpg so it was bawking. Running the advised `gpgconf --kill all` worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: best answer! for me, it was a fresh GPG setup so enabling GIT_TRACE led me to `No secret key`
After I ran `git config --global user.signingkey` I was then able to sign my commit. THANK YOU

Comment: @Dorian I had the same issue. Turns out I didn't set my git config email. As @asmeurer stated, make sure your git email (if it's set, you'll see a `user.email` line in `git config --list`) matches your gpg email (listed in `gpg --list-secret-keys`).

Comment: This answer helps a lot of git issues. One will get to know what is exactly being failed.

Comment: @Naman Try `echo "hello world" | gpg -bsau <key>`.

Comment: answers like this <3

Comment: This was perfect to debug why mine wasn't working, thank you. Turns out, if the window size is too small, gpg straight up fails `gpg: signing failed: Screen or window too small`. At office and the s^%tty monitor is tiny, so my split window is too small for gpg to show the modal

Answer (score 237):

Follow the below url to setup signed commit
https://help.github.com/en/articles/telling-git-about-your-signing-key

if still getting
gpg failed to sign the data fatal:
failed to write commit object

this is not issue with git ,this is with GPG
follow below steps

1. `gpg --version`
2. `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign`

if it is showing:

```
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

3. then use `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`
4. then again try `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign`
   in which PGP signature is got.
5. `git config -l | grep gpg`

```
gpg.program=gpg
commit.gpgsign=true
```

6. apply `git commit -S -m "commitMsz"`

Comment: `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` was the trick. Added that to my `.zshrc` file

Comment: Success with Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks! This wasn't the first Answer to offer `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`. The difference here is that @jayesh also offered a test and nothing about gpg2, fish, or brew which are not related (?) to anything in Ubuntu. This is also a more recent answer, which for my purposes means at this moment this answer might be better than those that are a couple years old. So good job on this short, effective, and up-to-date posting.

Comment: I confirm this works on WSL2! In Git Bash I didn't need to do this configuration i. e. The GUI appeared naturally. However, in WSL2, despite having GUI support via an X server, it didn't work without `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`. This worked beautifully.

Comment: Saved the day with `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`! Confirmed on `Kali ARM 5.4.83-Re4son-v7l+` and `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27`.

Comment: SAVED MY DAY (AND NIGHT). Can you tell what export GPG_TTY=$(tty) means?

Comment: for any body who face the issue that he/she want to enter this command in every new session you can add this step 3. and step 4 line in .bashrc

Comment: I confirm step 3 fixes the issue on Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. Also, if you have `commit.gpgsign=true` in `git config`, then the `-S` flag in `git commit -S -m "commitMsz"` does not seem to be necessary for the commit to be signed. Thanks!

Answer (score 173):

I've **DONE** it through this **short** and **easy** recipe:

Auto-sign commits on **macOS** (Globally and with different IDEs):

Get your `signingkey` in [this way](https://help.github.com/articles/telling-git-about-your-gpg-key/).

```
brew install gnupg gnupg2 pinentry-mac
git config --global user.signingkey <YOUR_SIGNING_KEY>
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
git config --global gpg.program gpg
```

Put the following in `gpg.conf` file (edit file with `nano ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` command):

```
no-tty
```

Put the following in `gpg-agent.conf` file (edit file with `nano ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` command):

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

**Update**:

As suggested in the comments, you might need to execute `killall gpg-agent` command after editing the configurations file, `gpg.conf`, according to the comments. needless to say that this command will terminate the GPG (Gnu Privacy Guard) agent.

Comment: Can you also explain what those commands are doing? It will help with understanding.

Comment: I also had to run a `killall gpg-agent` after setting the config files, then it worked!

Comment: How do we know we can trust the people behind `pinentry-mac`? I don’t say we can’t, but the GPGTools org is backup by a very small team and the repo has only 5 contributors vs using `brew install gnupg` which leverages the work of https://gnupg.org/.

Comment: In case it helps others, my issue was that I had an invalid local `user.signingkey` set, which I didn't notice in my sourcetree configuration, nor my global settings (because I didn't think to look at local config)

Ensure both local (`git config --local --get user.signingkey`) and global (`git config --global --get user.signingkey`) are the same, or even better, unset the local one if it is invalid (`git config --local --unset user.signingkey`)

Comment: on OSX (10.13.06), it gives the following error, bash: pinentry-program: command not found

Comment: On Apple Silicon with native brew, the path to `pinentry-mac` will be `/opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-mac`

Comment: Had the same problem moving from mac to Ubuntu. Make sure on Ubuntu you use `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` to restart the gpg agent and adjust the path to pinentry to `/usr/bin/pinentry`

Comment: If the `killall gpg-agent` does not work, simply restart your computer.

Comment: This still works in 2022! Would be nice if someone could explain why pinentry is needed.

Answer (score 120):

May help killing process `gpg-agent` that might stuck with old data. So new `gpg-agent` started would ask for password.

Comment: Use `gpg-agent --daemon` to start it

Comment: i had to restart gpg-agent as well

Comment: To kill process on macOS: `killall gpg-agent`

Comment: on ubuntu `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`

Comment: for Mac users: once the gpg-agent is killed, running the commit command asks for the password .. to not to redo the same steps again make sure to add the password to mac keychain

Answer (score 58):

To anybody who is facing this issue on **MacOS** machines, try this:

1. `brew uninstall gpg`
2. `brew install gpg2`
3. `brew install pinentry-mac` (if needed)
4. `gpg --full-generate-key` Create a key by using an algorithm.
5. Get generated key by executing: `gpg --list-keys`
6. Set the key here `git config --global user.signingkey <Key from your list>`
7. `git config --global gpg.program $(which gpg)`
8. `git config --global commit.gpgsign true`
9. If you want to export your Key to GitHub then: `gpg --armor --export <key>`
   and add this key to GitHub at GPG keys: https://github.com/settings/keys (with START and END line included)

**If the issue still exists:**

`test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo 'export GPG_TTY=$(tty)' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`echo 'export GPG_TTY=$(tty)' >> ~/.profile`

**If the issue still exists:**

Install https://gpgtools.org and sign the key that you used by pressing **Sign** from the menu bar: **Key**->Sign

**If the issue still exists:**

Go to: ‎⁨your global `.gitconfig` file which in my case is at: ‎⁨`/Users/gent/.gitconfig`
And modify the **.gitconfig** file *(please make sure Email and Name are the same with the one that you have created while generating the Key)*:

```
[user]
    email = gent@youremail.com
    name = Gent
    signingkey = <YOURKEY>
[gpg]
    program = /usr/local/bin/gpg
[commit]
    gpsign = true
    gpgsign = true
[filter "lfs"]
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

Comment: Adding 'gpsign = true' in .gitconfig fixed it for me

Comment: I had to run 'gpg-agent --daemon' and that fixed it for me (OS X, brew).

Comment: for Github client on Windows it works! After configure and add the gpg key (on *git bash*) you have to add the *gpg* to set *program = C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\gpg.exe* path on git configure; Uou cand fint the details on https://gist.github.com/xavierfoucrier/c156027fcc6ae23bcee1204199f177da

Comment: The `signingkey` was what I was missing in mine. Because I didn't have this, it was using my name and email from the config. I ran `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long` to get my signing key (the sequence of alphanumeric characters after the `/` on the `sec` line). I then ran `git config --global user.signingkey <signingkey>` replacing `<signingkey>` with what I got in the first step and my commits are now being signed

Comment: I have to add just the `git config --global commit.gpgsign true`, as @Pierre and I solve my problem. I have to enter a passphrase, the one I type when I create the key.

Answer (score 46):

My two cents here:

When you create and add a key to gpg-agent you define something called `passphrase`. Now that `passphrase` at some point expires, and `gpg` needs you to enter it again to unlock your key so that you can start signing again.

When you use any other program that interfaces with `gpg`, `gpg`'s prompt to you to enter your passphrase does *not* appear (basically `gpg-agent` when daemonized cannot possibly show you the input dialog in `stdin`).

One of the solutions is `gpg --sign a_file.txt` then enter the passphrase that you have entered when you created your key and then everything should be fine (`gpg-agent` should automatically sign)

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/624488/285117) on how to set longer timeouts for your passphrase so that you do not have to do this all the time.

Or you can completely remove the passphrase with `ssh-keygen -p`

Edit: Do a `man gpg-agent` to read some stuff on how to have the above happen automatically and **add the lines**:

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

**on your .bashrc** if you are using bash(this is the correct answer but I am keeping my train of thought above as well) then source your `.bashrc` file or relogin.

Comment: This solved my problem. Using `GIT_TRACE=1 git commit` as suggested somewhere did not yield any useful information so it was difficult to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 36):

I've seen similar answers, but nothing exactly like what worked for me. On Linux, I had to kill and restart my `gpg-agent` with:

```
$ pkill gpg-agent
$ gpg-agent --daemon
$ git commit ...
```

This did the trick for me. It looks like you do need to have `user.signingkey` set to your private key as well from what some other comments are saying.

```
$ git config --global user.signingkey [your_key_hash]
```

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS 10.15.6 with gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.23 installed from brew. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: this signingkey is from where? github/codecommit etc?

Comment: @JamieHutber you have to create your own signing key and add it to GitHub. You can follow the GitHub docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: I didn't realise you need to add them to github... got you. Though i'm using codecommit on AWS

Comment: @JamieHutber there should be a way to add the key to AWS as well. You follow similar instructions to create it and then you'll need to work with your admin or do some searching online to figure out how to add it to your profile on AWS. I am not as familiar with that setup.

Answer (score 28):

I get that error every time I logout then login again on my macOS.  The solution is just a simple single command:

```
killall gpg-agent
```

I think it's just an error from gpg agent, kill it then working again.

Answer (score 27):

On OS X, using `gnupg2` via brew I just had to **kill the gpg agent**, happens sometimes:

```
pkill -9 gpg-agent
```

And set the `env` variable if needed:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

See [Common GPG problems](https://www.gnupg.org/(it)/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Common-Problems.html) also and [this answer here too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0/42265848#42265848)

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I have created a new alias `alias fix-gpg='pkill -9 gpg-agent && export GPG_TTY=$(tty)'`.

Comment: This works fine, thanks. Didn't even need to set the env variable afterward.

Comment: I had to kill the gpg agent after reinstalling python. It started working afterwards.

Answer (score 19):

The git trace was very revealing for my situation...

```sh
   GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -m "a commit message"
```

```sh
   13:45:39.940081 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git commit -m 'a commit message'
   13:45:39.977999 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau 'full name <your-email@domain.com>'
   error: gpg failed to sign the data
   fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I needed to generate an initial key per the format that `git` was checking against. It's best to copy the value passed to `-bsau` above in the logs as is and use below.

So it becomes,

```sh
   gpg --quick-generate-key "full name <your-email@domain.com>"
```

Then it worked.

Comment: mate...you cannot image how many hours i spent trying to sort this out until i reached your Answer ... it was the naming of the key all along .. thank you! thank you! thank you!

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1360557/144977

Answer (score 12):

Update Oct. 2016: [issue 871](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/871) did mention "Signing stopped working in Git 2.9.3"

[Git for Windows 2.10.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.10.1.windows.1) released two days ago (Oct. 4th, 2016) has fixed Interactive GPG signing of commits and tag.

> the recent gpg-sign change in git (which introduces no problem on Linux) exposes a problem in the way in which, on Windows, non-MSYS2-git interacts with MSYS2-gpg.

---

Original answer:

Reading "[7.4 Git Tools - Signing Your Work](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work)", I assume you have your "[`user.signingkey`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36811656/6309)" configuration set.

The last big refactoring (before Git 2.10) around gpg was in [commit 2f47eae2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f47eae2a1337bd0cb50dbc936df6433f460bb4a), here that error message was moved to [`gpg-interface.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2f47eae2a1337bd0cb50dbc936df6433f460bb4a/gpg-interface.c#L77-L78)

A log on that file reveals the recent change in [commit af2b21e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af2b21ec3cab346fcb19f5794eec6317330cd2a3) (Git 2.10)

> gpg2 already uses the long format by default, but most distributions seem to still have "gpg" be the older 1.x version due to compatibility reasons.  And older versions of gpg only show the 32-bit short ID, which is quite insecure.
>
> This doesn't actually matter for the *verification* itself: if the
>   verification passes, the pgp signature is good.
>   But if you don't
>   actually have the key yet, and want to fetch it, or you want to check
>   exactly which key was used for verification and want to check it, we
>   should specify the key with more precision.

So check how you specified your `user.signingkey` configuration, and the version of gpg you are using (gpg1 or gpg2), to see if those have any effect on the error message.

There is also [commit 0581b54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0581b546419627d4e82f7df8b195fa207ef42f6a) which changes the condition for the `gpg failed to sign the data` error message (in complement to [commit 0d2b664](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d2b664efd815a3f6432723adb41732d90cc9be1)):

> We don't read from stderr at all currently. However, we will want to in a future patch, so this also prepares us there (and in that case gpg *does* write before reading all of the input, though again, it is unlikely that a key uid will fill up a pipe buffer).

[Commit 4322353](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4322353bfb53a83e6657af50603d3521ee9d7d0c) shows gpg now uses a temporary file, so there could be right issues around that.

> Let's convert to using a tempfile object, which handles the
>   hard cases for us, and add the missing cleanup call.

Comment: I do have my `user.signingkey` config set. Also using `gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.3`.

Comment: @nullpointer I have edited my answer. Can you check if the issue persists with Gti For Windows 2.10.1.

Comment: sorry for the late update, working on MacOSX not Windows so couldn't verify this.

Comment: Another potential issue with Windows users is if they have installed gnupg in adddition to the version of gnupg that ships with git -- `gpg --list-keys` won't give the same output as `"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe" --list-keys` thus, git won't find your key when trying to sign a commit because it's using the "wrong" `gpg`

Comment: @sytech Good point, the PATH needs to be carefully set, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah. Although, editing the environment in which git runs is... potentially complicated, particularly because it can depend on how you install/configure git on Windows. (PATH won't be the same in your shell and in the environment git uses). FWIW, the workaround I found was to copy the "real" `gpg.exe` with a new name like `gpgwin.exe` in the same directory then set `git config --global gpg.program gpgwin`.  That way, there's no naming conflict.

Comment: @sytech Right, I remember having to do the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849206/6309

Answer (score 11):

I got this error on Ubuntu 18.04 and it turned out that my **key was expired**.

To see this, I ran this and it confirmed that my keys were expired:

```sh
gpg --list-keys
```

To correct this, I ran (using the ID displayed in the previous command):

```sh
gpg --edit-key <ID>
```

From there, I extended the expiration of `key 0` and `key 1` following [these instructions](https://www.g-loaded.eu/2010/11/01/change-expiration-date-gpg-key/) which boiled down to typing `key 0` then `expire` and following the prompts. Then repeating for `key 1`.

Afterward, to test this, I ran:

```sh
echo test | gpg --clearsign
```

And before the fix, it failed with the error:

> gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
>   gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No secret key

But after the fix, the same command successfully signed the message so I knew things were working again!

Comment: Confirming this fixed an issue when importing a valid key from Mac OSX Catalina to CentOS7. Fought with this beast for well over two hours trying to figure out why it kept asking for a password amongst other things. Oddly enough it was already set to never expire, and I set it to still never expire.

Answer (score 10):

Using cygwin, I recently switched to `gpg2`. Then I had the same problem for signing with git after setting `git config gpg.program gpg2`.

Try `echo "test" | gpg2 --clearsign` to see whether gpg2 is working. I found it the easiest solution to just set `git config gpg.program gpg`, because that works. But you will also get a better error this way - e.g. that you need to install pinentry.

Comment: Actually, on some Linux distros you may end up with the same issue. Git always uses gpg, not gpg2. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766123/signing-commit-with-openpgp-subkey-fails#34767663

Comment: This revealed for me the error `gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device` which can be solved by `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`. Source: https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues/issues/2798

Answer (score 9):

If you use homebrew on a M1 chip without Rosetta, you need to specify a different location of the pinentry-program binary because it's installed at a different place.

Andy Hayden's updated answer should be modified as follow:

```
brew upgrade gnupg  # This has a make step which takes a while
arch -arm64 brew link --overwrite gnupg
arch -arm64 brew install pinentry-mac
echo "pinentry-program /opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-mac" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
killall gpg-agent
```

Comment: For some reason, signing stopped working on my M1: `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign` output was `gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`. 
This worked for me.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. Though everything was already installed for the arm64 target for me, you also don't have to specify `arch -arm64` every time if you are on m1, [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666134/how-to-install-homebrew-on-m1-mac) to install brew for m1

Comment: @Shawn Koh best easy working answer for all the answers provided kudos

Answer (score 8):

Might be a hanging gpg-agent.

Try `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` [as discussed here](https://superuser.com/a/1150399)

Answer (score 7):

I am using **M1 Mac**, where I have tried above most common of the solutions and didn't work, my problem was that GPG binary missing here => `usr/local/bin`

Originally, I installed GPG via `brew` and I tried re-installing it but couldn't find the binary where it stored, later I installed GPG Suite GUI from here => [GPG Suite Tools](https://gpgtools.org/) and it worked.

Finally, I can sign-in commit and get verify badge on Github.

Comment: This trick worked for me and it should work for anyone who is with M1 Mac. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I must have accidentally updated gpg somehow because I got this after trying to test if gpg works:

```
gpg: WARNING: server 'gpg-agent' is older than us (2.1.21 < 2.2.10)
gpg: Note: Outdated servers may lack important security fixes.
gpg: Note: Use the command "gpgconf --kill all" to restart them.
```

Running `gpgconf --kill all` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon this error not because of any configuration issue, but because my key was expired. The easiest way to extend its validity on OSX is to open the GPG Keychain app (if you have it installed) and it will automatically prompt you to extend it. Two clicks, and you're done.

Answer (score 6):

I found it very helpful to check what `git commit` is doing under the hood. Run the following commit with `GIT_TRACE=1` as follow:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -S -m "MESSAGE"
```

This will show what user name, email and signing key git uses when committing.

In my case, I found that git was picking up the wrong user's and key details for signing the commit. I mainly intended to use the local config of the repo rather than the global and adding the following to the local git config (located at "REPO_PATH/.git/config") got signing the commit to work both in Terminal and VSCode

```
[user]
    name = USER NAME
    email = USER EMAIL
    signingKey = SIGNING KEY
```

It can also be set with the following:

```
git config --local user.name "USER NAME"
git config --local user.email "USER EMAIL"
git config --local user.signingkey "USIGNING KEY"
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning GIT_TRACE=1 , that helped me get to the root cause of my issue.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem. I'm happy to report that the issue lies not with `git 2.10.0` but with `gnupg 1.4.21`.

Temporarily downgrading gnupg to 1.4.20 fixed the issue for me.

If you're using homebrew and you upgraded your packages like I did, you can probably just run `brew switch gnupg 1.4.20` to revert back.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have your email set properly.

```
git config --global user.email "user@example.com"
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, was helpful to follow the correct method of generating a GPG key via [github](https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/)

Comment: In my case the problem was that I was using a company e-mail in a specific repo, for which I didn't have PGP key generated.

Comment: Since this question comes up on Google quite often, this really helpful answer should be way higher up in the answers list. Before uninstalling and installing a ton of software trying to fix something that's not broken, just check that you've specified the right e-mail address.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was with the relative name of `gpg` inside `~/.gitconfig`. I changed it to this and the problem disappeared (Monterey, Macbook M1):

```
[gpg]
    program = /opt/homebrew/bin/gpg
```

The explanation is simple: when `git` is trying to run `gpg` it does it in a new shell, without running `~/.profile` where I configure `PATH` for homebrew. So, it simply can't find `gpg` at all.

Answer (score 4):

If the email assoicated to your GPG key's uid is different to the email you are using in git, you'll need to add another user id to your key OR use a key which email matches exactly.

You can add another UID by using:

> $ gpg --edit-key

See for mo https://superuser.com/questions/293184/one-gnupg-pgp-key-pair-two-emails

Answer (score 4):

The answers above are great but they did not work for me. What solved my issue was exporting both the **public** and **secret** keys.

list the keys from machine where we are exporting from

```
$ gpg --list-keys
/home/user/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
--------------------------------
pub 1024D/ABCDFE01 2008-04-13
uid firstname lastname (description) <email@example.com>
sub 2048g/DEFABC01 2008-04-13
```

export the keys

```
$ gpg --output mygpgkey_pub.gpg --armor --export ABCDFE01
$ gpg --output mygpgkey_sec.gpg --armor --export-secret-key ABCDFE01
```

go to machine we are importing to and import

```
$ gpg --import ~/mygpgkey_pub.gpg
$ gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import ~/mygpgkey_sec.gpg
```

bingo bongo, you're done!

reference: https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-importexport-gpg-key-pair/

ps. My keys were originally made on bootcamp windows 7 and I exported them onto my mac air (same physical machine, different virtually)

Answer (score 4):

This started happening all of a sudden for me on Ubuntu, not sure if some recent update did it, but none of the existing issues were applicable for me (I had `GPG_TTY` set, tried killing the agent etc.). The standalone `gpg` command was failing with this error:

```
$ echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

test
gpg: signing failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Operation cancelled
```

I tried running `gpg` with `--debug-all` option and noticed the below output:

```
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- INQUIRE PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 27472 gnome3 1.1.0 /dev/pts/6 screen-256color -
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> END
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- ERR 83886179 Operation cancelled <Pinentry>
gpg: signing failed: Operation cancelled
```

The above indicates that there is some issue with the `pinentry` program. Gpg normally runs `pinentry-curses` for me, so I changed it to `pinentry-tty` (I had to `aptitude install` it first) and the error went away (though I no longer get the fullscreen password entry, but I don't like that anyway). To make this change, I had to add the line `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and kill the agent with `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` (it gets restarted the next time).

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me, I usually use my IDE terminal.

I got this error every now and then, in most cases it worked just fine.
I found out the issue after running

```
 echo "test" | gpg --clearsign

gpg: signing failed: Screen or window too small
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Screen or window too small
```

The solution: just increase terminal window size.

Comment: This is so stupid but the solution worked

Answer (score 4):

Apart from not having setup your gpg key with git correctly, another possible problem:
Trying to commit from inside an ssh session with X forwarding.
In this case it could try to invoke a GUI which will fail if the env var `DISPLAY` isn’t set.

You can force gpg-agent to use a tty-only tool by editing your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty
```

Then reload the conf:

```
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

(of course install pinentry-tty first)

Comment: `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye` was the key for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After searching a lot, I found that gpg key was the issue in my case.

To check if gpg key is an issue for you, first check output of the following:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -m 'message'
```

If something is wrong then you will see something like:

```
10:37:22.346480 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau <your GPG key>
```

It was showing my name and email in GPG key here but this should have the key. You can try running `gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau <your GPG key>`

To update your correct key, do the following:
check key using: `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long`

It should have the following output:

```
/Users/hubot/.gnupg/secring.gpg
------------------------------------
sec   4096R/3AA5C34371567BD2 2016-03-10 [expires: 2017-03-10]
uid                          Hubot 
ssb   4096R/42B317FD4BA89E7A 2016-03-10
```

And then update the key using:

```
git config --global user.signingkey 3AA5C34371567BD2
```

Now check the commit again and it should success if key was the issue. You need to set the passphrase to update the key which you can do using GitHub docs.

More details are at: https://gist.github.com/paolocarrasco/18ca8fe6e63490ae1be23e84a7039374

Answer (score 3):

If you're like me and using `WSL` along with your IDE, you might've faced this problem since the passphrase 'window' never shows up when committing using the IDE's commit interface (WSL doesn't support GUI apps yet)

The fix was to simply use the command line git as that has its own cli window for you to enter your passphrase. You also need to make sure that the terminal is 'big' enough for it to popup (surprising I know)

[image: signing commits using WSL]

Comment: i still don't believe this fixed my issue. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error , after VSCode update. Although my security commit was working fine,  after update of VSCode I got this error:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

The only thing that restored the functionality was this command:

```
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

The command returned error with this:

```
gpg: signing failed: Screen or window too small
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Screen or window too small
```

After increasing the terminal i was able to type my pass phrase. Very bizzare situation.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with the latest Git sources (2.12.2) built along with the latest sources of all its dependencies (Zlib, Bzip, cURL, PCRE, ReadLine, IDN2, iConv, Unistring, etc).

It turns out `libreadline` was giving GnuPG problems:

```
$ gpg --version
gpg: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.7: undefined symbol: UP
```

And of course, trying to get useful information from Git with `-vvv` failed, so the failure was a mystery.

To resolve the PGP failure due to ReadLine, follow the instructions at [Can't update or use package manager -- gpg error](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1484848):

> In terminal:
>
> ```
> ls /usr/local/lib
> ```
>
> there was a bunch of readline libs in there (libreadline.so.BLAH-BLAH)
>   so i:
>
> ```
> su
> mkdir temp
> mv /usr/local/lib/libreadline* temp
> ldconfig
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If this just happened randomly and has been working perfectly in the past, as is my case, try logging out (`cmd+shift+q`) and logging back in. Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Very much like @birchlabs, after a lot of digging/searching I found that it wasn't GPG, but rather GPG Suite.  I did `cask reinstall gpg-suite` and it solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and got the same error, was worried for weeks too.
Finally realized that gpg2 is not pointing towards anything.
So simply run

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg
```

And tada, it works like charm.

[image: Signed commit]

Your commits will now have verified tag with them.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, none of the solutions were working because I did not manually go into my `~/.gitconfig` and remove the following as I created a new key that was no longer my older X.509 key so I removed the following and then my new key began to work.

```
[gpg]
    program = gpg
    format = x509
[gpg "x509"]
    program = smimesign
```

Answer (score 2):

If your issue is with *Visual Studio Code* not allowing to commit, but you have already set up your GPG signature the one line answer with `bash` is:

```sh
git config --global gpg.program `which gpg2`
```

If you have `gpg` in `PATH` but not `gpg2` then just use it instead.

Answer (score 2):

Solution work for me is :

- Firstly I tried to get details about why this is NOT working. Try below cmd on terminal

```
   $ echo "Hello" > test.txt
   $ gpg --sign --default-key <your-email-id> test.txt
```

- Observed error with details : **gpg: signing failed: No pinentry**

> ```
> gpg-agent[59045]: can't connect to the PIN entry module '/usr/local/bin/pinentry': IPC connect call failed
> gpg-agent[59045]: failed to unprotect the secret key: No pinentry
> ```

- From terminal I hit below cmd :

```
    cat ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

- Check if below statement is present. **Need to add if not present in gpg-agent.conf**

> pinentry-program
> /usr/local/MacGPG2/libexec/pinentry-mac.app/Contents/MacOS/pinentry-mac

- After adding pinentry path, Run

```
    $ gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
    $ gpg --sign --default-key <your-email-id> test.txt
```

- See the output :

```
 gpg: using <your-email-id> as default secret key for signing
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers seemed to match my problem. My `gpg` binary (`/usr/local/bin/gpg -> /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg2`) was installed as part of [GPG Suite](https://gpgtools.org/), rather than by brew.

Nevertheless, I felt that the advice boiled down to: "use whichever `gpg` binary is the latest available on brew". So I tried:

```
brew update
brew upgrade git
brew install gpg

# the following are suggestions from brew's Caveats, to make `/usr/local/bin/gpg`
# point to the brew binary:
rm '/usr/local/bin/gpg'
brew link --overwrite gnupg2
```

I verified that I had correctly changed the `gpg` upon my `$PATH` to point to the new executable from brew:

```
 which gpg
/usr/local/bin/gpg
 ls -l /usr/local/bin/gpg
lrwxr-xr-x  1 burger  admin  33 Feb 13 13:22 /usr/local/bin/gpg -> ../Cellar/gnupg2/2.0.30_3/bin/gpg
```

And I also explicitly told git which `gpg` binary to use:

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg
```

*Well, maybe that's not completely watertight, as it's sensitive to path. I didn't actually go as far as confirming beyond doubt that git had switched to invoking the brew `gpg`.*

In any case: none of this was sufficient to make `git commit` successfully sign my commits again.

---

The thing that worked for me ultimately was to *update GPG Suite*. I was running version 2016.7, and I found that updating to 2016.10 fixed the problem for me.

I opened `GPG Keychain.app`, and hit "Check for updates…". With the new version: signed commits worked correctly again.

Comment: I tried updating to latest version... that didn't work either.  trying to sign in xcode.

Answer (score 1):

got it setup by simply :

```
brew uninstall gpg 

brew install gpg2
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the solutions mentioned in other answer worked. I found out that the problem was specific to one repository. Deleting and cloning the repo again solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a weird one, but make sure your terminal is big enough! You can tell if it's too small by running `echo test | gpg --clearsign` -- it'll give you a pretty obvious error message letting you know. If it's not big enough, your GPG agent can't display its little ncurses box.

This one won't apply if you use a GUI agent or something that doesn't use ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

For me, `brew` had updated the `gnupg` or `gpg` so all I had to do to fix this is.

```
brew link --overwrite gnupg
```

That linked the `gpg` to the right place, as I can confirm via `which gpg` and everything worked after that.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this in `prezto` another `zsh` variant. There the issue was my `git` repo was new and did not have the `node_modules` added to `.gitignore`. As soon as I added the `node_modules` to `.gitignore` the issue was no more to be seen. So my assumption is `git-info` was taking time due to these large `node_modules`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue **without** killing `gpg-agent` on every restart:

Check if you have multiple copies of `gpg` and `gpg-agent`:

```bash
$ which -a gpg-agent
/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg-agent
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg-agent

$ which -a gpg
/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg
/usr/local/bin/gpg
/usr/local/bin/gpg
```

For me, there were some leftover binaries from old Macbook migrations installed by `MacGPG2`.

Removing those binaries (and symlinks) and checking again to make sure there is only one copy:

```
$ which -a gpg
/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg

$ which -a gpg-agent
/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg-agent
```

Then restart your computer one last time.

`gpg` should sign correctly without needing to kill anything:

```bash
$ echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

test
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Comment: GPGTools - https://gpgtools.org

iQIzBAEBCgAdFiEE1S8n.....
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

(Reposted from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75505131/1472186) since this question has higher votes)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with brew to install gpg, which seems to run into problems from time to time, just download gpg tools from [GPG Tools](https://gpgtools.org).

As you go through the wizard, click on customize install and deselect the mail plugin (unless you want to use it). These tools seem to work without running into any problems, plus it remembers your passphrase after the first time you sign you commit. No extra configuration needed, other then telling [git about which key](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/telling-git-about-your-signing-key) to use.

At least that has been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

These few commands in order seem to be working with me as I personally have has the same issue after upgrading to Mac OS 12.4

```
brew upgrade gnupg
brew install pinentry-mac 
echo "pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf 
killall gpg-agent && gpg-agent --daemon
git config --global gpg.program gpg
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **OSX terminal instead of the integrated VS Code** terminal worked for me. The VS Code integrated terminal has allowed me to gpg sign this same repo up until today. Previously when I had this error, I fixed it by updating VS Code, but this time updating didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to stumble upon Sascha Doemer's [elegant solution](https://gist.github.com/saschadoemer/5c1873f44e9188e03d4e044bf22217d7) (slight modification on my part; store as `gpg-no-tty` in the user's `PATH` directory --- `~/bin` or `~/.local/bin` --- and remember to `chmod +x gpg-no-tty`):

```bash
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/gpg --batch --no-tty "$@"
```

Then, if needed for a single repository (or switch to `--global` to set the global value of the configuration entries):

```bash
git config --local user.signingkey "${YOUR_SIGNING_KEY}"
git config --local commit.gpgsign true
git config --local gpg.program gpg-no-tty
```

Note:
I tried editing a previous answer, but there were too many edits pending.

In my particular case, I was getting this error while trying to commit changes with the Emacs' Version Conrol (VC) with the magic `C-x v v` + `C-c C-c` key combination (leaving this note for future Emacs users with the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error when I was using Github Desktop for Windows. After I closed and reopened the program Github Desktop, the passphrase window appeared, and I was able to commit my changes. Most probably this happened because my Github Desktop was open during the GPG key creation and setup.

Answer (score -2):

Check if gpg is enabled using below command

```
git config -l | grep gpg
```

if it returns true, Run the below command to disable it

```
git config --global --unset commit.gpgsign
```

After successfully running above command, You should be able to run git commit command.

Comment: This disables all GPG signing without fixing the problem.