# Git error - gpg failed to sign data

Tags: git, gnupg

I just started using git and I install git and gpg via homebrew.
For some reason, I get this error when i do `git commit`
I looked at so many other stackoverflow questions regarding this topic and none of them worked for me.
How can I fix this error so that I can upload successfully.

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Comment: For Mac users. I had this issue. Advice on this page helped me realize I may have two versions of gpg installed and I did. One from brew and one from GPG Suite. I wanted to use the GPG Suite one since it allows for caching passphrase in system keychain. Uninstalling the brew version resolved my issues. Along with @sideshowbarker's answer about killing gpg-agent. So I assume the configurations of each were interfering with one another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object \[Git 2.10.0\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502146/git-gpg-onto-mac-osx-error-gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data

Comment: I just ran into an issue with gpg signing, the problem was that my git repo didn't have it's local gpg.signingkey set, but the gllobal one was.

So just set `git config --local user.signingkey` to the correct key and it'll autosign again.

and maybe unset the global one with `git config --global --unset user.signingkey`

Comment: Apart from what others said, I also had to make sure that my user.email matched what I entered when generating the key:  `git config --global user.email 'SAME EMAIL'`

Comment: I have the same problem on macOS (Ventura). After testing it with `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign`, I have found out that there is a problem with `gpg` itself. Therefore, I added `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 504, accepted):

For troubleshooting, two things to first try:

- run `gpg --version`, and make sure you have GnuPG version 2+ (not version 1) installed
- run `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign`, to make sure `gpg` itself is working

If that all looks all right, one next thing to try:

- run `brew install pinentry` to ensure you have a good tool installed for passphrase entry

If after that install, you re-try `git commit` and still get a "`failed to sign the data`" error, do:

- run `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` to kill any running agent that might be hung

---

Otherwise, some basic steps to run to check you’ve got a working GnuPG environment:

- run `gpg -K --keyid-format SHORT`, to check that you have at least one key pair that is not expired

If the output of that shows you have no secret key for GnuPG to use, you need to create one:

- run `gpg --gen-key`, to have GnuPG walk you through the steps for creating a key pair

---

If you get an error message saying *“Inappropriate ioctl for device”*, do this:

- run `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` and/or add that to your `~/.bashrc` or `˜/.bash_profile`

Comment: I get this error when I run the second command: gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
gpg: [stdin]: clearsign failed: No secret key

Comment: @Entitize That seems to indicate gpg doesn’t think you have any keys to use for signing. See the additional steps I added to the answer; if you’ve never run `gpg2 --gen-key` before, that’s what you need to do first.

Comment: When I run that command it gives me: gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input. UPDATE: I deleted no-tty from ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf and it looks like its working. Ill update you if it does or doesn't work

Comment: Ok, I set up my email stuff. It still doesn't work though. It gives me the same error

Comment: when I run echo "test" | gpg2 --clearsign, it gives me: gpg-agent[-]: command get_passphrase failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: problem with the agent: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: no default secret key: Operation cancelled
gpg: [stdin]: clearsign failed: Operation cancelled. I've tried so many other possibilites, but none work. Is there a way to use GIT without GPG!

Comment: You might try `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`. As far as if there’s a way to use git without gpg, you should be able to do that by default or else just by running `git config --global commit.gpgsign false` to globally unset gpg signing of your commits.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I appreciate your help, but the way I fixed it was to delete the gpg configuration from my git.

Comment: A `brew install pinentry-mac`, updating `~/.gpg/gpg-agent.conf` to use it and then `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` did the trick. Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: this part ( `git config --global gpg.program gpg2`) has been saved my life! :)

Comment: Here in Mac OS X, I started to debug with `echo "test" | gpg2 --clearsign`, found an error and it leads me to [this thread](https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues/issues/2798), which solved my problem: I just put an `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` into my `˜/.bash_profile` file and then reloaded with `source ˜/.bash_profile`

Comment: I was missing he `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` part. I'm guessing when i installed gpg, that session had GPG_TTY set, so as soon as I started a new session I lost it.

Thanks for such a comprehensive fix all for gpg :D

Comment: My problem is that I have a Git repository owned by the root user that I can access with `sudo`. Normally in order to use this repo, I use `sudo -E git ...`. However it does not appear that gpg can sign this repository with my own keys. What's the solution for when you use gpg signing but you're on a repository owned by the root user that you access through `sudo`?

Comment: When running the `echo test` command I get `gpg: signing failed: Screen or window too small`. Why is there a minimum window size and how do I bypass this check?

Comment: For those interested in `gpg2`: In contrast to the standalone version gpg, which is more suited for server and embedded platforms, this version is installed under the name gpg2 and more targeted to the desktop as it requires several other modules to be installed.

Comment: `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` <-- This is what I needed. Thank you!!

Comment: My issue was simple and silly: I had mistyped my `git config --global user.signingkey` command and thus had the wrong key in. This guide helped a lot to eliminate errors, but I would have solved it even quicker if had just looked at `cat ~/.gitconfig`

Comment: this `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign` got me on the right track. my `code` was failing on gpg signing, but running that gave me the following output: ```-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

test
gpg: signing failed: Screen or window too small
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Screen or window too small``` so i increased the size of the terminal window _et voilå_ :-P

Comment: Can I add one to your list? I have had signing fail because my terminal window was too small in the past.

Comment: I'm using oh-my-zsh and the `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` finally did it for me! Thank you kind man

Comment: also in case wonderng to check the signatures it's possible to use `git show --show-signature -s` or `git log --show-signature`

Answer (score 171):

Git needs to know which key it is signing with.

After you have setup GPG, gpg-agent, and your gpg.conf files (see [this guide](https://github.com/pstadler/keybase-gpg-github)), you need to run

```
git config --global user.signingKey EB11C755
```

Obviously, replace the public key at the end with your own. If you want every commit to be signed by default, use

```
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
```

---

```
$ gpg2 -K --keyid-format SHORT          # <-- Shows your keys, e.g.:
/home/<username>/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-------------------------------
sec   rsa4096/0754B01E 2019-02-02 [SCA]             <--secret key
      C396BF3771782D7691B0641145E11B080754B01E
uid         [ultimate] John Doe <user@domain.com>
ssb   rsa4096/A20AB8EC 2019-02-02 [E]               <--public key

sec   rsa4096/25C504D5 2019-02-02 [SCA] [revoked: 2020-06-01]
      08BFF49B9E07E4B4B0C4946B645B6C1425C504D5
uid         [ revoked] John Doe <user2@domain.com>
uid         [ revoked] [jpeg image of size 2670]
```

Where `A20AB8EC` is the key ID you're looking for from this example.

Comment: I just ran into this in case anyone else was foolish enough to do what I did:

Make sure you spell it "signingkey" and not "signinkey".

Comment: literally this comment by @ZNK did it for me. I had spelled it "signkey" instead of "signingkey"

Comment: The accepted answer should cite this as the first troubleshooting step, because sometimes you have all your keys already in place, it's just git forgets which key to use.

Comment: If you are still getting this error try unsetting your local config with `git config --local --unset user.signingkey` and `git config --local --unset commit.gpgsign`. I had a different, invalid, key set as my local key and that was causing this error.

Comment: This helped me solve it, by changing my signing key!

Comment: on macos, it should be signingkey not signingKey with camel case.

Answer (score 94):

I am using it. It has support for zsh and works on *Windows Subsystem for Linux*:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

Other users  have confirmed that above is the only change required for *MacOS* (e.g. Catalina 10.15.7). For Macs add above to ~/.zshrc.

Proved to work also in Linux containers in Windows with WSL2.

Comment: I'm using zsh on MacOS Catalina and this was the only change I needed to get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: I was receiving the error in the OP after copying my keys to my WSL environment, turns out I needed to do this to provide a prompt for the passphrase on the key. Thanks.

Comment: this was also the solution on Ubuntu over SSH

Comment: Over SSH you might need to find your ssh tty (echo $SSH_TTY) and use that for GPG_TTY too.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on RHEL 8.3. `GPG_TTY=$SSH_TTY git commit ...` did the trick.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! I put this into my profile and now I can sign commits whenever I want.

Comment: i have checked at this link: https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html and added two lines first="GPG_TTY=$(tty)" 
second="export GPG_TTY" it works now

Comment: When using Fish it's : `export GPG_TTY='(tty)'`

Answer (score 68):

Somehow your git is configured to GPG sign every commit.  Signing with GPG isn't required to commit or push using git.  It's likely giving the error because your gpg signing mechanism isn't configured yet.

If you're new to git, try to get it working first without GPG signing at first, then add signing in later if you really need it.

You can verify how your git is configured with regards to gpg by doing:

```
git config -l | grep gpg
```

Which may produce zero or more lines, including:

```
commit.gpgsign=true
```

If "commit.gpgsign" is true, then you have gpg signing enabled.  Disable it with:

```
git config --global --unset commit.gpgsign
```

Then try to run your commit again.  It should now run without gpg signing.  After you get the basic git working, then you should try adding gpg signing back to the mix.

Comment: Awesome! `git config --global --unset commit.gpgsign` worked for me :)

Comment: This works lol as there is now no feature for gpg signing so, i upvote

Comment: Kudos! I disabled globally and still stuck , then I grep all and noticed it is still enabled locally `git config -l | grep gpg` God bless  you!

Comment: Very helpful answer for diagnosis.  I'm returning to git after a long hiatus and some of my remembered settings and configurations needed updating.

Answer (score 55):

Check for your key to be expired. Once you fix the expiration date (no need to create a new key unless you want to), `git` will work as normal.

*One way to fix the expired key:*

(Note: `$` represents command line prompt, type the commands after the prompt; press Enter after each command)

`$ gpg2 --list-keys` to find the appropriate key id (characters after `\` on `pub` line)

`$ gpg2 --edit-key <key id>` - this opens the gpg shell, with prompt changed to `gpg>`

`gpg> expire` - follow instructions to set new expiration date for primary key

Next, if there are subkeys that are expired (`sub` shows on the line), reset their expiration dates, too:

`gpg> key 1` - selects first subkey
`gpg> expire` - follow instructions to set new expiration date for subkey

Repeat for each subsequent subkey, as needed.

`gpg> save` - saves the expiration dates changes

Comment: I have had this problem every time I've tried to run a gpg key that didn't have an expiration date. For some reason git doesn't like that. Using this method to add an expiration date (no matter how far in the future) seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Don't forget to type `save` at the gpg prompt when you're done!

Comment: Another way to fix: run "gpg keychain" app (if you use it). If a key is expired it will ask you if you want to renew it, click on "yes".

Comment: On Ubuntu, `gpg` may be enough for the command (no need for `gpg2`.

Answer (score 54):

Refer to @sideshowbarker, and @Xavier Ho solution, I solved my problem via following steps.

Assume gpg2 installed by brew,

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg2
brew install pinentry
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
gpg2 -K --keyid-format SHORT
// no key found then generate new one
gpg2 --gen-key

gpg2 -K --keyid-format SHORT
```

> .../.gnupg/pubring.gpg

> sec   rsa2048/**0A61C6FC** 2017-06-29 [SC] [expires: 2019-06-29]

```
git config --global user.signingkey 0A61C6FC
```

Reminded by my colleague, need to append

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

to ~/.zshrc if using zsh, else append to ~/.bash_profile

---

### For macOS,

the gpg2 is combined with gpg in brew and hence the gpg command is pointed to gpg2

```
brew install gpg2
```

> brew info gpg

> gnupg: stable 2.2.6 (bottled)

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg
gpg -K --keyid-format SHORT
```

and there has pinentry-mac for passphrase entry

```
brew install pinentry-mac
vim ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

Add line

> pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac

Reminded by my colleague, need to append

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

to ~/.zshrc if using zsh, else append to ~/.bash_profile

Comment: macOS 10.15 (Catalina) ships with GnuPG version 2.2.17 so there's no need to install it separately unless you plan to manage updates on your own.

Comment: For macOS users: fell free to create the ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: That setting `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` helped for Windows 10 Ubuntu WSL as well

Comment: on macOS  11.5 zsh. happened after gpg upgrade. agent was already running and there was actually a version mismatch. kill agent did the trick! ty

Answer (score 23):

## Solution:

```
Issue: Disabled loopback pinentry mode
```

> To solve the problem, you need to enable loopback pinentry mode in **~/.gnupg/gpg.conf**:

```bsh
cat <<'EOF' >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf

use-agent 
pinentry-mode loopback

EOF
```

> And also in **~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf** (create the file if it doesn't already exist):

```bsh
cat <<'EOF' >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf

allow-loopback-pinentry

EOF
```

> Then restart the agent with `echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent` and you should be good to go!

[Source](https://d.sb/B5N)

Comment: Wow, after spending hours trying every possible solutions, this fixed my problem, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks to the source actually. I was stuck with this too.

Comment: I was having a very hard time getting anything else to work during a SSH session and this fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: This answer is the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 10):

**This worked for me on ubuntu 18.04**

**Check your gpg key**

```
gpg -K --keyid-format LONG
```

**if you get a blank response ,generate a GPG key**

```
gpg --generate-key
```

rerun the first command, you should get an output as:

```
sec   rsa3072/95A854E0593B3214 2019-05-06 [SC] [expires: 2021-05-05]
      AF2F7514568DC26B0EB97B9595A854E0593B74D8
uid                 [ultimate] yourname<your_email>
ssb   rsa3072/EFD326E6C611117C 2019-05-06 [E] [expires: 2021-05-05]
```

**set git signing key**

```
git config --global user.signingkey 95A854E0593B3214
```

then you are good to go! (`--global` is optional)

**Alternatively if you don't mind signing with your ssh key**

```
git config commit.gpgsign false
```

**note that this is not recommended due to a security issue according to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953867/what-are-the-advantages-of-signing-git-commit-with-gpg-key-compared-to-ssh-key) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412164/gpg-vs-ssh-keys)**

Comment: "Alternatively if you dont mind signing with your ssh key" what does ssh have to do with signing?

Comment: SSH doesn't have anything to do with signing commits. They are referring to turning off GPG commit signing, and depending on using SSH keys to authenticate when you actually push your commits to a git server. You can push (and it is quite common) to push unsigned commits using SSH authentication.

Answer (score 10):

I had to fix the gpg.program to the absolute path to gpg:

```
git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"
```

I am using Windows with cygwin.

Comment: This was the solution for me. I have installed gnupg using chocolatey.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. I had done `choco install gpg4win`

Comment: You save my day! Thank you!

Comment: This fixed problem for me, with cygwin and gpg2 installed.

Answer (score 8):

If it used to work and just stated failing, kill the agent and try again:

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

Check if the agent is up again:

```
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

Answer (score 7):

If you had your pinentry and gpg setup up before, and it stopped working out of nowhere:

Check if your gpg works:

```sh
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

If it says `gpg: signing failed: No pinentry`,
just restart the gpg daemon client, which gets stuck from time to time:

```sh
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

Now it should be working:

```sh
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

Comment: Thank you! This was all that was needed for me after verifying that gpg signing key was not expired.

Answer (score 6):

Use **GIT_TRACE=1** to see where Git failed then check all custom configurations used by Git and where they are defined then override according to your need with :

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -S -m "this will tell you wich intern git command failed"

git config --list --show-scope --show-origin
```

For me I had the `error: gpg failed to sign the data` and `fatal: failed to write commit object` because Git was using *****smimesign***** by default for some reason, even if I unset `gpg.x509.program` key, and [*****smimesign***** couldn't find my key](https://github.com/github/smimesign/issues/59#issuecomment-518702343).

So I had to explicitly tell Git to use *****gpg***** instead :

```
git config --local gpg.x509.program gpg
```

Comment: Good call on the `GIT_TRACE`. It showed me the failing `gpg` command line it was running. When I ran it manually, that showed me the "Unusable secret key" that it skipped.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this problem after upgrading to gnupg 2.x. It would seen that gpg2 is referencing keys differently: I still had `signingkey = ABC98F11` (gpg v1 setting) in my `~/.gitconfig`. The key identifiers for gpg2 are longer. Look them up with `gpg --list-secret-keys`

Answer (score 3):

This error can also occur when your GPG key has expired. Generating a new key and adding it to Git should resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

For me this error started to occur with `git tag -s` on Debian GNU/Linux when I switched from `pinentry-gnome3` to `pinentry-curses` (using `update-alternatives --config pinentry`) for easier remote access. It only occurred with `git tag -s`, not with `gpg` (e.g. `gpg --clearsign`) itself.

The sole change necessary to get it working again in this case was to add `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to my shell startup files.

I though didn't get the “Inappropriate ioctl for device” error message mentioned as indicator for this fix in another answer to this question.

*Note: Since the cause for getting this error was a completely different one than for those who suggested `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` before (usually as a side hint) in other answers to this question, I decided this question needs another answer which mentions that `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` may be the main fix and sole thing necessary in some cases.*

Comment: Thanks! `update-alternatives --config pinentry` did it for me. I am SSH'd into my desktop and `pinentry` was set to `/usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3` (which *should* have a TTY fallback when SSH'd in or when switched to a virtual console). But it wasn't working, apparently. Setting the default to `/usr/bin/pinentry-tty` did the trick for me. I might have to set it back when I get back to my desktop, but, for now, I'm good. `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` was not enough. I did it but needed to switch `pinentry` before I was able to sign my commit.

Comment: Depending on whether you are using an *alternatives* setup or not - (in my case **not**, as I am on FreeBSD) - you might need to tweak what `pinentry` is linked to. I was in a KDE Desktop environment and that link was pointing to `pinentry-tty` and I was getting the same error as the OP. However changing it to be a link to `pinentry-qt5` made things "work" - which is fortunate as I am using an OpenGPG smart-card and some elements of the signing (& encryption!) setup are not physically accessible!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this error occurred when running `git commit` on a small `tmux` window that was not able to fit the passphrase prompt.

```
$ echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

test
gpg: signing failed: Screen or window too small
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Screen or window too small
```

Comment: Yeah this one is a doosey!

Comment: This should be the top answer because it's easiest to resolve quickly lol

Answer (score 1):

I had made a `git` key with 3 separate keys for `certify` / `sign` / `encrypt` & the key showed as expired in the future (after working fine for a few days):

```
pub   rsa4096/4CD1E9DA 2017-04-26 [C] [expired: 2017-04-28]
      Key fingerprint = 4670 59C1 7592 08B8 7FA5  313B 2A42 B6A6 4CD1 E9DA
uid         [ expired] Stuart Cardall (GIT Development Keys) <xxxxxx>
sub   rsa4096/5195E715 2017-04-26 [E] [expired: 2019-04-26]
sub   rsa4096/DB74C297 2017-04-26 [S] [expired: 2019-04-26]
sub   rsa2048/A3913A3C 2017-04-28 [] [expired: never     ]
```

made a new key without adding separate subkeys to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was making sure the key's name matched my git user name. I assume the emails have to match too. This might have to do with me using GPG KeyChain on my Mac. Not sure.

I thought I was naming the key when I filled this out, but I guess it was asking for my name (git user name).

[image: GPG Keychain form]

Comment: It's a pity this answer is so far down behind that many will not get here looking for their issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on macos - to try and troubleshoot I tried listing keys to see if they had expired using `gpg2 --list-keys` - I verified that the keys had not expired and that the proper key were set in my config using `git config --global user.signingkey`.

After I had run those commands I was suddenly able to do signed commits again without problems. I did not change my config files or keys - I did not even create a fresh Terminal instance. It just seemed like the gpg2 was somehow in a weird state on my mac.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to match the name stored in GitHub settings to the name and comment of the key.

So if `gpg --list-keys` returns `uid [ultimate] Joe Blogs (fancy comment) <email@example.com>` your name in .gitconfig should be `Joe Blogs (fancy comment)`.

Initially, I had my name set as `Joe Blogs` and GPG would not find my key and show the "no secret key" error in `strace`. Unfortunately, that error didn't appear without `strace` and one would get the generic

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot, I found that gpg key was the issue in my case.

You can try running `gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau <your GPG key>` if your GPG key is correct.

To update your correct key, do the following:
check key using: `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long`

It should have the following output:

```
/Users/hubot/.gnupg/secring.gpg
------------------------------------
sec   4096R/3AA5C34371567BD2 2016-03-10 [expires: 2017-03-10]
uid                          Hubot 
ssb   4096R/42B317FD4BA89E7A 2016-03-10
```

And then update the key using:

```
git config --global user.signingkey 3AA5C34371567BD2
```

Now check the commit again and it should success if key was the issue. You need to set the passphrase to update the key which you can do using GitHub docs.

More details are at: https://gist.github.com/paolocarrasco/18ca8fe6e63490ae1be23e84a7039374

Answer (score 0):

May be your Git config was set ***gpgsign = true***. Try to set it to false if you dont want asign your commits. Go to your repository folder and change the file

> nano .git/config

From this...

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:yourrepo/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
    signingkey = <GPG-KEY>
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
```

To this...

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:yourrepo/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
    signingkey = <GPG-KEY>
[commit]
    gpgsign = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem installing `brew install gpg2` then doing `git config --global gpg.program gpg2`

Answer (score 0):

Same error can also be caused when you have expired key in your git config.

Please check the content of `cat .git/config` and look for `signingkey` value and check if it is expired. If yes update it with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **smart card/yubikey** to store your GPG key and you set the `signkey` of git config by the key stored in the card (and all the answer above seem not to resolve your issue), your blocked PIN of the card might be the root cause of this issue.

To check the blocked PIN:

```
gpg --card-status
```

If the counter is similar to

```
Reader ...........: Yubico YubiKey
PIN retry counter : 3 0 3
```

**Then your PIN is blocked** (after 3 unsuccessful tries).

To unblock the PIN:

```
gpg --card-edit
gpg/card> admin
Admin commands are allowed

gpg/card> passwd
gpg: OpenPGP card no. … detected

1 - change PIN
2 - unblock PIN
3 - change Admin PIN
4 - set the Reset Code
Q - quit

Your selection? 2
PIN unblocked and new PIN set.

1 - change PIN
2 - unblock PIN
3 - change Admin PIN
4 - set the Reset Code
Q - quit

Your selection? q
```

Answer (score 0):

For me a simple `brew unintstall gnupg && brew cask reinstall gpg-suite` solves the issue.

It uninstalls the (in my case) manually homebrew-istalled gpg and reinstalls the whole GPG Suite.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had mixed gpg configuration and smimesign configuration given in the commit signing documentation here: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/telling-git-about-your-signing-key

After working on it for hours, I found the best way to correct it was unset everything related to gpg, and reconfiguring gpg.

As mentioned in @Jason Thrasher's answer, find all the git config related to gpg using:

```
git config -l | grep gpg
```

Then unset everything golablly as well as locally using:

```
git config --global --unset <config_name>
git config --local --unset <config_name>
```

Then reconfigure following the official documentation given above.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, I am using gpg2

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue just now when VSCode updated. I figured the GPG agent was hanging, as the command took a good few seconds to run before erroring out. Running `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` reset that and fixed it for me.

Comment: When you do that gpg-agent just starts again next time you sign something with GPG.

Comment: @Zenul_Abidin That's the point. I just needed to kill it to get it out of whatever rut it was in, and when it started up again it worked fine.

Comment: I don't know why off-and-on-again works when it does, but it does. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank you, VSCode was not able to get the password to signin the commit. After restarting the agent as suggested it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For my Linux system with a GUI and gpg 2.2.19, neither killing gpg-agent (which starts itself again), unsetting `$DISPLAY` or setting `$GPG_TTY` worked for me because it was trying to use **pinentry-gnome** to ask for the password from the console. And my key had not expired.

From a SuperUser answer for a similar question, [How to force GPG to use console-mode pinentry to prompt for passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/520980/how-to-force-gpg-to-use-console-mode-pinentry-to-prompt-for-passwords), the problem can also occur if your system has a GUI such as GNOME, and your package manager is configured to use a GUI pinentry program, which is the reason why it’s hanging.

I had to switch to **pinentry-tty** to get GPG to sign messages again. On Ubuntu, this can be done using steps from the link which I will quote here:

```
sudo apt install pinentry-tty
sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry
```

The second command will show you a list of pinentry programs and ask you to type a number to select one, so type the one corresponding to pinentry-tty, and then without any additional effort, signing messages (and git commits) should work again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on both linux/windows platforms and in my case I just needed to pay more careful attention to the output.  This was mind-boggling because I could use the same setup to sign commits in other repos.

```
git commit -m "test signing"
gpg: skipped "***63231079***": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I added emphasis on the "skipped" line.  Please note that sometimes when you clone a repo they had a key assigned:  this issue had me so befuddled that I nuked the forked repo I had access to and re-forked on github.  Then because I was thinking "global config" I never thought to look at the local repo config, and when I did I noticed this:

```
[user]
    signingkey = 63231079
```

Well, of course it wouldn't work nimrod, git defaults to local settings first so that's why your key never picked up.   I set the pointer via `git config` and It's worked ever since.

Answer (score 0):

*What is gpg*: GNU Privacy Guard

*usage*:

> GPG is an excellent method to ensure secure communication between two parties. It allows sensitive information to be easily shared across an insecure network.

Simple solution:

Step1: check if the key is expired please do

> gpg -K --keyid-format SHORT

Step2: In case its not expired

> git config --global user.signingkey

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows powershell(5.1+), I guess this command will work.

1. get gpg program path with this command.

```
(Get-Command gpg).Path
```

2. after get path, copy path.
3. use this command

```
git config gpg.program <your path>
```

try to commit.
Happy coding!!!

Answer (score -2):

Fail-safe option that worked for me: reboot my machine.

It's heavy handed, and it probably won't stop the problem from popping up again eventually. But I had the same problem, tried solutions from just about every answer, no luck.

Adding it here in the hopes that it unblocks someone else in my situation :)

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, it had been working for literal years for me and suddenly stopped working. I tried every answer to this question and nothing worked (and `gpg --clearsign` worked fine). Rebooted and it worked again.

Comment: Even this didn't help me

Answer (score -8):

This will help you to get rid of it

`git config commit.gpgsign false`

Comment: I don't understand the down vote, it solved the proposed issue like a charm for me.

Comment: This command should be avoided. It will only remove the requirement to sign the git commit, not resolve the issue of authenticating the person who is making the commit.