# git - gpg onto mac osx: error: gpg failed to sign the data

Tags: git, macos, gnupg

I installed GPG from brew.

```
brew install gpg
```

It is gnupg2-2.0.30_2.

When I commit, I do get a error message:

```
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Max Mustermann (mycomment) <mm@test.de>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 1111AAAA, created 2017-01-05 

error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I used the command:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys | grep ^sec
```

and it gives me back:

```
sec   2048R/1111AAAA 2017-01-05
```

Then I used this command:

```
git config --global user.signingkey 1111AAAA
```

commit gives me back the same error message.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0 (Possible duplicate)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052538/git-error-gpg-failed-to-sign-data (Possible duplicates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object \[Git 2.10.0\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0)

Comment: I had a similar issue, after a year of stable operation, although my GPG key didn't expire.

All I had to do was to run `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` and it started to work again.

Comment: Why is this a Stack Overflow question (as opposed to [unix.se]) at all? This is a command-line tool usage question, not a development question.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

If you’re not getting prompted at all for a passphrase, the solution may just be to install a program to facilitate that. The most common is [pinentry](https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/pinentry/index.en.html).

```
brew install pinentry-mac
```

So installing that and trying again *may* get things working. But if not, another thing to do is make sure `git` it using/finding the right GPG program. These days you really should be using `gpg2`, so if you don’t already have that installed, do this:

```
gpg --version
```

…and make sure it indicates you have GnuPG version 2+ (not version 1) installed.

If you already have GnuPG 2+ and `pinentry` installed, then try this:

```
echo "pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

…or, more robustly:

```
echo "pinentry-program $(which pinentry-mac)" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

…and then try again.

And you may also need to stop `gpg-agent`:

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

You don’t need to manually restart it — it will get restarted automatically when it’s needed.

**Note:** Some commenters mention needing to reboot after making changes — but it seems likely the only effect of that is to cause `gpg-agent` to be restarted. So manually killing `gpg-agent` as described above should be sufficient.

Comment: Installing `pinentry-mac` solved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: I am having the same issue, despite performing all of these steps.

Comment: I followed the above steps but needed a reboot before this worked

Comment: MacOS Mojave is the root of all evil. After I upgraded to Majave all my homebrew apps stopped working including gnupg. I recomplied them all and it started working.

Comment: For me restarting the gpg-agent worked so I didn't need to restart: `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`

Comment: I had to kill `gpg-agent` and start it again using `gpg-agent --daemon`

Comment: I got the error `gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input` when try to use `gpg --full-generate-key`. If you get this error just remove the line
`no-tty`

from `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` or `~/.gnupg/options`

Comment: I had to restart gpg-agent like @MohammadBanisaeid said

Comment: in my case, `git config --global gpg.program gnupg` works even though I install it via homebrew this ways: `brew install gnupg2`

Comment: I just ran a brew upgrade, which of course updated only these things: `openssl`, `pinentry`, `libgcrypt`, `gnupg` (the perfect isolated chaos to break things). It seems after the update I just needed to restart the gpg agent with: `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` and then when I went to try and commit again things were fixed 

Comment: Latest homebrew on M1 changes the bin dir, use this: `echo "pinentry-program $(which pinentry-mac)" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

Comment: In my M1, `brew install gpg` already gives GnuPG 2.

Comment: It works! And if you have installed `pinentry-mac` with brew on latest MacOS(currently is 12.6), It will be installed at `/opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-mac`

Answer (score 92):

To anybody who is facing this issue on **MacOS** machines, try this:

1. `brew uninstall gpg`
2. `brew install gpg2`
3. `brew install pinentry-mac` (if needed)
4. `gpg --full-generate-key` Create a key by using an algorithm.
5. Get generated key by executing: `gpg --list-keys`
6. Set the key here `git config --global user.signingkey <Key from your list>`
7. `git config --global gpg.program /usr/local/bin/gpg`
8. `git config --global commit.gpgsign true`
9. If you want to export your Key to GitHub then: `gpg --armor --export <key>`
   and add this key to GitHub at GPG keys: https://github.com/settings/keys (with START and END line included)

**If the issue still exists:**

`test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo 'export GPG_TTY=$(tty)' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`echo 'export GPG_TTY=$(tty)' >> ~/.profile`

**If the issue still exists:**

Install https://gpgtools.org and sign the key that you used by pressing **Sign** from the menu bar: **Key**->Sign

**If the issue still exists:**

Go to: ‎⁨your global `.gitconfig` file which in my case is at: ‎⁨`/Users/gent/.gitconfig`
And modify the **.gitconfig** file *(please make sure Email and Name are the same with the one that you have created while generating the Key)*:

```
[user]
    email = gent@youremail.com
    name = Gent
    signingkey = <YOURKEY>
[gpg]
    program = /usr/local/bin/gpg
[commit]
    gpsign = true
    gpgsign = true
[filter "lfs"]
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

*p.s*
I took this answer from my previous answer here:
[gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object [Git 2.10.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0/55646458#55646458)

Comment: The GPGTools is what did it for me, it seems that prompts for the passphrase and then adds it into the keychain :)

Comment: Thanks man! Far better then the current accepted answer for me

Comment: Signing using the GPGTools was what did it for me! Isnt there a way to sign the key using gpg cli?

Comment: Note that "Stack Snippets" are our local JSFiddle equivalent -- they're only for JavaScript, CSS, HTML, and otherwise code that can run in a browser. Use the `{}` button instead of the snippet button otherwise.

Comment: I was missing "gpg --full-generate-key" and this is exactly what the error log was complaining about. Thank you very much for the detailed answer

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error message and found that my key was expired.
So it might be a good idea to check your key expiration with:

`gpg --list-keys`

If your key is expired as well you can adjust the expiration date with:

`gpg --edit-key <YOUR_KEY>`

and then:

```
gpg> expire
...enter the new expiration date...
gpg> save
```

Comment: Many answers mention using `gpg --list-keys` to check if a key exists then otherwise create a new one. But nobody says to pay attention to the expiration date. There's a single character difference between `[expires: YYYY-MM-DD]` and `[expired: YYYY-MM-DD]` that can easily overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

I ran `brew upgrade` on macOS and it broke my gpg signing in git, presumably when it updated the gpg package. I assume there's an easier way to force the gpg service to restart correctly (I assume something that was actively running broke when I upgraded the package), but my fix for this was pretty simple: Just restart your computer.

Comment: Indeed this just happened to me. `killall gpg-agent` was the process that needed a swift kick in the ...

Comment: @MikeHardy amazing ... I tried everything and this unexpected command just fixed it (got the issue after upgrading to Monterey)

Answer (score 0):

Install [GPGSuite](https://gpgtools.org/) instead , it has GUI for generating the key.

You can see more details [here](https://medium.com/@rwbutler/signing-commits-using-gpg-on-macos-7210362d15)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting problems in macOS,
open `~/.gitconfig`
and change anything below `[gpg]` to
`program = /usr/local/bin/gpg`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the **user.signingkey** was setting wrong....Copy the right signingkey the problem solved

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to you after installing Xcode, your git binary may have been replaced.  (This particular solution assumes you are managing your git install with homebrew.)

Symptoms:

1. You are not prompted for a passphrase
2. Your error message is

   ```
   error: gpg failed to sign the data
   fatal: failed to write commit object
   ```
3. `$ git config --global gpg.program` throws an error
4. You see a system git instead of one installed by homebrew:

   ```bash
   $ which git
   /usr/bin/git # should be /usr/local/bin/git with homebrew
   $ ls -l $(which git)
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  167072 Feb  6  2022 /usr/bin/git
   # should be a symbolic link with homebrew:
   # lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  28 Aug 16 12:11 /usr/local/bin/git -> ../Cellar/git/2.37.2/bin/git
   $ git --version
   git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)
   ```

In this case the solution is to install or reinstall git with homebrew.

```bash
$ brew install git
# <output>
# then restart your terminal
$ ls -l $(which git)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  28 Aug 16 12:11 /usr/local/bin/git -> ../Cellar/git/2.37.2/bin/git
$ git --version
git version 2.37.2
```

Don't forget to restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue **without** killing `gpg-agent` on every restart:

Check if you have multiple copies of `gpg` and `gpg-agent`:

```bash
$ which -a gpg-agent
/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg-agent
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg-agent

$ which -a gpg
/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg
/usr/local/bin/gpg
/usr/local/bin/gpg
```

For me, there were some leftover binaries from old Macbook migrations installed by `MacGPG2`.

Removing those binaries (and symlinks) and checking again to make sure there is only one copy:

```
$ which -a gpg
/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg

$ which -a gpg-agent
/opt/homebrew/bin/gpg-agent
```

Then restart your computer one last time.

`gpg` should sign correctly without needing to kill anything:

```bash
$ echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

test
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Comment: GPGTools - https://gpgtools.org

iQIzBAEBCgAdFiEE1S8n.....
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```