# Git GPG: gpg failed to sign the data

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gnupg, gpg-signature

I have an error with signing my commits by `git commit -S -m 'test'` and getting these errors:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41054093/13762818) and still not working right.

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41506446/13762818) and still nothing.

I have Macbook Pro 2017 with the latest macOS.

Is there any other solution how I can fix it and properly commit my commits to Github or Gitlab?

Comment: Please add the results of showing your key with gpg; I suspect the key has expired.

Comment: @U.Windl The gpg key was today created and today set. It can be still expired? If yes how I can check it?

Comment: Would git display exact information about the GnuPG invocation via `GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -S -m 'test'` ?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky Terminal display this. 16:27:37.452431 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git commit -S -m test
16:27:37.466454 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: gpgsm --status-fd=2 -bsau xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use S/MIME instead of OpenPGP signatures, is it by intention? This article should be helpful on further troubleshooting: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Git: gpg failed to sign the data' in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067967/git-gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I solved it by:

1. First ensure that the key is not expired: `gpg --list-keys`
2. If it is still valid restart the gpg-agent: `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`
3. It should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed here using this command of topic: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130415

```
$ export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
$ echo "test" | gpg2 --clearsign
```

Answer (score 0):

First, [make sure to use Git 2.40](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75645281/6309) (Q1 2023), which clarifies the error message.

---

Git 2.36 (Q2 2022) also improves that use case: newer version of GPGSM changed its output in a backward incompatible way to break our code that parses its output.
Adjustments have been made to accommodate these changes.

See [commit b0b70d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0b70d54c4a17476f04ce17255c6558425c11367), [commit fa47dd6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa47dd6445faea84300844f7d70fe22e710bdc22) (04 Mar 2022) by [Todd Zullinger (`tmzullinger`)](https://github.com/tmzullinger).
See [commit a075e79](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a075e79d2c036e8e41900cfcb2177d75b92758c8) (04 Mar 2022) by [Fabian Stelzer (`FStelzer`)](https://github.com/FStelzer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 21b839e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21b839e606c173efa942dc282b3b6b542d7242f5), 13 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`gpg-interface/gpgsm`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a075e79d2c036e8e41900cfcb2177d75b92758c8): fix for v2.3
>
> <sup>Helped-By: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Helped-By: Todd Zullinger</sup>

> Checking if signing was successful will now accept '[GNUPG]: `SIG_CREATED`' on the beginning of the first or any subsequent line.
> Not just explictly the second one anymore.
>
> Gpgsm v2.3 changed its output when listing keys from `fingerprint` to `sha1/2 fpr`.
> This leads to the gpgsm tests silently not being executed because of a failed prerequisite.
> Switch to gpg's `--with-colons` output format when evaluating test prerequisites to make parsing more robust.
> This also allows us to combine the existing `grep`/`cut`/`tr`/`echo` pipe for writing the `trustlist.txt` into a single `awk` expression.
>
> ```
> git merge --no-ff -m msg signed_tag_x509_nokey &&
> GNUPGHOME=. git log --graph --show-signature -n1 plain-x509-nokey
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I already had GPG on my Windows PC, and `gpg --list-keys` would successfully list my key **in Git Bash** (not in the standard Windows Command Line), however, GitHub Desktop wasn't working for me.

The solution was to add Git's GPG binary to my PATH variable. So I added `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to the PATH, and GitHub Desktop began working.

**NOTE:** If you have Git installed on your PC, you likely already have GPG installed at: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe`.