# git commit -> gpg failed to sign data (macOS Monterey, all things up to date)

Tags: git, gnupg, sign

Looked into all other similar postings, with some fairly old and not applicable, and [one more recent and close to my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70196715/git-gpg-gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data), with no actual resolution.

Attempting to commit a local branch change, failing with the gpg signing, then running the following, to collect data maybe useful to those in the know:

platform: Monterey macOS (12.4)

% git --version
git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)

key expire time: 2032

% GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -S -m "my-local-branch"

Output:
17:03:31.062430 exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git

17:03:31.062692 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

17:03:31.063037 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git commit -S -m here_goes_branch_name

17:03:31.065514 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau here_goes_my_actual_key

error: gpg failed to sign the data

fatal: failed to write commit object

Any pointers?