# Git GPG signing fails without a clear message

Tags: git, github, gnupg

If I set my Git to sign with my GPG key it fails. I've tried GIT_TRACE and it doesn't really give me any more info:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git commit
15:29:35.112157 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'commit'
15:29:35.115745 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'code --wait' '/Users/b/VurbAgency/haarlem.github.io/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG'
15:29:52.884006 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'gpg' '--status-fd=2' '-bsau' 'SECRETKEYID'
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

When I try to run `'gpg' '--status-fd=2' '-bsau' 'SECRETKEYID'` it just hangs after saying `BEGIN_SIGNING H8` and doesn't do anything anymore.

Any ideas on how to solve this or avenues as to research?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41052538/8804293

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I stumbled upon this when encountering the same error and I was already on the latest version of gpg (2.2.17). For me, it turned out to be multiple things.

1. Before committing I had to run `$ export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`. This then prompted the passphrase prompt to appear.
2. If I used a passphrase with a special character it didn't work (the prompt said I had a bad passphrase when trying to use), so I had to only use alphanumeric characters.

And if you're doing this to get verified commits on GitHub ensure the name and email address match what you have on GitHub.

Comment: Nothing happens for me when I run `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`

Comment: Same here for me, the command does nothing. Did you ever find a solution to this?@ReinstateMonica3167040

Comment: I also had to add `gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye >/dev/null` along with `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to my `.bashrc`. This made the GPG password prompt (`gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau <id>`) appear correctly. Found the fix on the Arch Wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#Configure_pinentry_to_use_the_correct_TTY

Comment: THANK YOU--this worked for me. Next time I tried to commit, I entered my passphrase and *poof* no more can't sign data error

Answer (score 13):

If you have installed gpg using Homebrew, and are also using GPGTools, you need to uninstall Homebrew's gpg.

```
# Uninstall gpg in homebrew so that it uses the gpg in GPGTools instead
$ brew uninstall gpg

# You might need to do some extra cleanup afterward as well:
$ rm -r /opt/homebrew/etc/gnupg

# Restart the gpg-agent so that it uses the correct one:
$ gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

After that, git was able to sign my commits again.

Comment: This was it for me! After a computer restart, my computer decided to use Homebrew's gpg.

Comment: This was it! When I was setting up GPG I was overzealous and installed packages I didn't need. Thanks to this comment I now know I wasn't over-prepared, I was just shooting myself.

Answer (score 4):

I've updated GPG on my mac using `brew upgrade gpg` after I saw my GPG was at version 2.2.5 and the newest was 2.2.10.

This has fixed the issue, for now. However, I still have no idea about what the cause of this problem was.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. In the GnuPG configuration file `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, the `pinentry-program` path was pointing to `pinentry-mac`, which was missing.

Running `brew install pinentry-mac` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error: `BEGIN_SIGNING H10`.

On OSX, To fix it I ran `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`