# Git error: gpg failed to sign the data on Linux

Tags: linux, git, sign

I am having trouble signing commits. With the following git config:

```
user.name=Bob
user.email=[bob's email]
user.signingkey=ABCDEFGH
user.user=bob1
gpg.program=gpg2
```

I was told to include only the first eight characters of the secret key.

After staging, upon `git commit -S -m "commit message"`, I receive the following errors:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

It seems that most users who encounter this error are on Macs and have some extra setup to do. But I'm on Kali Linux.

Any advice?

Comment: [Gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39494631/608639). `git commit -vvv -S ...` may provide more information.

Comment: @jww that did not change the output for me at all. My Signing key was **simply expired**.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I was told to include only the first eight characters of the secret key.

The value of `user.signingkey` is a **key id** identifying which key git should use when generating the signature.

There's a complete example [in the official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) that shows how this should work.  If `gpg --list-keys` shows something like:

```
/Users/schacon/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
---------------------------------
pub   2048R/0A46826A 2014-06-04
uid                  Scott Chacon (Git signing key) <schacon@gmail.com>
sub   2048R/874529A9 2014-06-04
```

Then the key id is `0A46826A`:

```
git config --global user.signingkey 0A46826A
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I misunderstood the key length. I was providing the first 8 because 2048R uses eight, while RSA4096 outputs a longer key. After cleaning the git config and setting the values with --global (specifying the full key), it worked!

Comment: One of the missing nail. The other one, is the email associated with the `gpg` key should be verified by github. Go to your github profile and add this new email into your github profile, after which, github will send you a verification email and when you click the button from that email then your `gpg` key shall then be marked as verified. At first, I thought that doing a signed commit push to one of my repo will verify my `gpg` key but it didn't. Secondly, I also thought that publishing my `gpg` key to `keyserver.ubuntu.com` will verify my `gpg` key, but it didn't.

Comment: This is the only one that helps for me. I am using macOS with gpg2 and pinentry-mac.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same problem using WSL (Ubuntu). Working solution for me was adding `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` into `~/.bashrc`, [thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41054093/9007136).

Answer (score 4):

For those who followed the answer but could not make it work. There is a chance that you had tried *other* solutions and accidentally did this (which is for MacOSX, not Linux)

> git config --global gpg.program=gpg2

You should only do that if you are using MacOSX.
For Linux, you can fix it by `unset`-ing that entry first by running this command (because your system uses `gpg` **NOT** `gpg2`).

> git config --global --unset gpg.program

Now you can follow the *accepted answer* in this page to tell Git to use your key.

Comment: `git config --global --unset gpg.program` helped me, thanks!