# gpg "failed to write commit object"

Tags: macos, code-signing, gnupg

I'm trying to enable commit signing on OS X Mojave.

```
git commit -S -am "Test"
```

The error is:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

What I tried:

- `gpg` works fine (see below), did not install `gpg1` or `gpg2`
- Installed GPG KeyChain and added a new key (even added a separate sign-only subkey whithin)
- Installed `pinentry`
- `gpg2 --clearsign` works fine (generates a new .asc file for files, outputs text for plain text)

Questions I looked into and tried every option:

- [gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object [Git 2.10.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0)
- [Git error - gpg failed to sign data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052538/git-error-gpg-failed-to-sign-data/41054093)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you are looking to get added to a repo instead of init git-crypt in your repo, youll need to let someone who already has access to the encrypted files to add your public key to the `/.git-crypt/...` part of the repo

Comment: Thanks @mewc, but that was not the case, see my own answer below

Comment: Cool, more of an fyi for the next person. Didnt feel it deserved its own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, of course, right after I posted this question, I found the solution.

So my problem was that I followed this doc: https://help.github.com/en/articles/telling-git-about-your-signing-key

And set up both `GPG` and `smimesign`, when I have Git < 2.19 and no proper X.509 keys.

So I just removed the part with `smimesign` from global `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: Exact solution for could not find the user id in specified key while commiting

Answer (score 59):

I also had this problem. I found a good solution.
Just try to sign a file before you commit.

```sh
$ touch a.txt
$ gpg --sign a.txt
```

Then, the OS will let you input the password.
If this step is OK, now you can commit by signing correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it saved me a lot of time!

Comment: But why is this needed?

Comment: This worked, but why this has to be done? Is this a bug?

Comment: Thanks! This helped me figure out the true issue:  my terminal window was too small to render the password prompt. It seems like `git` sometimes hides the error information from surfacing.

Comment: Brilliant, saved me the trouble of doing all of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0

Comment: Hello from 2022! Thank you very much for this answer!

Comment: This is needed if you've set a passphrase!

Comment: @OliverTappin but passphrase is always needed whenever you add a new key, no?

Answer (score 22):

I just added the key ID to the global config

list all keys:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

Select the one you added to github and set it.

```
git config --global user.signingkey [public key ID]
```

Answer (score 3):

To prompt you to enter a PIN or passphrase when required, install `pinentry-mac`

```
$ brew install pinentry-mac
$ echo "pinentry-program $(which pinentry-mac)" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
$ killall gpg-agent
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck in Android Studio terminal because can't see passphrase input field.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `echo "foobar" | gpg --clearsign`. It should ask for your key's passphrase and return the signature.
If instead you see the following error message:

> error: gpg failed to sign the data 
> fatal: failed to write commit object

You might want to try running `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`. If after testing again you're prompted for the password and it works, run this everytime on startup, adding it to `~/.bashrc`, which is actually required according to gpg-agent's documentation, as mentioned in [this dev.gnupg thread](https://dev.gnupg.org/T3412) and which you can verify with `man gpg-agent`.

I also found [this gitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/paolocarrasco/18ca8fe6e63490ae1be23e84a7039374) very useful.

Answer (score 1):

At least, that error message will be clearer:

Error messages given upon a signature verification failure used to discard the errors from underlying `gpg` program, which has been corrected with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023).

See [commit ad6b320](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad6b320756d8d9150291c696a02c86d1c2f0f4b2), [commit 8300d15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8300d15d5ecea1e41b2b1d381238ccaaec501dd4) (15 Feb 2023) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 38a227b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38a227b796653d61a21d9b31e44e48dd66f647e0), 24 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`gpg`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad6b320756d8d9150291c696a02c86d1c2f0f4b2): do show gpg's error message upon failure
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> There are few things more frustrating when signing a commit fails than reading a terse "`error: gpg failed to sign the data`" message followed by the unsurprising "`fatal: failed to write commit object`" message.
>
> In many cases where signing a commit or tag fails, `gpg` actually said something helpful, on its stderr, and Git even consumed that, but then keeps mum about it.
>
> Teach Git to stop withholding that rather important information.