# git commit - gpg failed to sign the data, but works from console

Tags: git, gnupg, archlinux, kde-plasma

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but basically, `git commit` gives me

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

However, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57442957/11720290), I can sign commit by signing a random file via gpg in the command line first. This works, but it is pretty annoying. Why do I have to do that ?

I'm using Manjaro KDE.

Comment: When you do the command-line file signing, do you have to feed a password / pass-phrase to a GPG agent, which then lingers for a while to be able to sign the commit without first getting a password / pass-phrase? If so, consider tickling the agent to do the same pre-load without having to sign a file. That's still annoying, so [see the documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html).

Comment: @torek yes, the password is saved because I can enter it in the terminal, but when I let VSCode or Intellij Idea commit and do stuff, if the password isn't "temporary saved" it does that error. I didn't understand what you wanted me to do with the documentation.

Comment: It *may* be the case that you can set GPG_TTY to point to a terminal where you can enter the password. I'd poke around with the documentation to see if there is some workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Alvin Tang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12716154/alvin-tang) for giving me the solution that was so simple!

I just had to add these two line:

```sh
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

at the bottom of the file located at `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to specify the GPG program for Git with

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg2
```

and enable signing for all commits (otherwise, add `-s` to each Git command)

```
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
```

Use `gpg --list-keys` to find your key and specify the use of this key in Git:

```
git config --global user.signingkey <Your GPG Key>
```

GPG will ask for the password when you execute `git commit`.

Reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work

Comment: Have you also added `GPG_TTY=$(tty)` and `export GPG_TTY` to `.bashrc`?
You might like to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42265848/12716154).