# GPG not prompting for passphrase

Tags: key, gnupg, passphrase

So up until yesterday gpg was working all fine. But today, it doesn't prompt for passphrase, I just get an empty blinking command line.

I'm using gpg for signing git commits. I thought the problem was with git. But no, if I do `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign`  I get the same than when doing `git commit`(empty command line not prompting for passphrase).

At first, the error I was getting when doing `git commit` was

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

But in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052538/git-error-gpg-failed-to-sign-data) they said to `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` in your bashrc/zshrc
if you get that error. That stopped gpg from showing the error `error: gpg failed to sign the data` but it still doesn't prompt for passphrase.

I can't do anything related to prompting for passphrase, not listing my keys with gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG` or anything. I can see my public with no problem. I tried importing my private key again and I get:

```
gpg: key <KEYID>: "<NAME EMAIL" not changed
```

And then just a empty command line again.

I have `pinentry` installed just in case anyone asks.

I don't understand. It was all working fine yesterday! Does anyone knows how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and it turned out the `gpg-agent` process was hung.

You might try running:

```
killall gpg-agent
```

And then re-try:

```
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

Comment: Nah that didn't work, I had to restart my computer and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you might try running:

```
ps -ef |grep pinentry
```

kill the result and try again.

Comment: hi what's the command to kill the results?

Comment: `kill -9 pid`, `pid` is the result of the previous command.

Comment: thanks @leechor What does `-9` mean?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html

Comment: ah i see, it's the total number of the output record