# Git - cannot run gpg after $ git commit

Tags: git, macos

I'm commiting my GIT repository and terminal shows some issues.

After I type `$ git commit` terminal display editor with where I must uncomment line where is **Initial commit** so I done it at departure from editor I type `:wq`, terminal get me back to default screen and display this errors

```
error: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

In `$ git status` I have following things

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   app.js
    new file:   index.html
```

Repository was created, all files is **TRACKED** and files can't be commited.

I'm beginner so sorry for some issues.

Comment: Have you had a look at this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631.
**tldr** try `git config --global gpg.program gpg1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error tells you that when the gpg was attempted to be executed, the program was not found, so, if you will need to [set up gpg](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key). When that's done, you will need to find out which are the GPG keys which have both public and private keys:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
```

From the keys you see, choose the one which you intend to use and run

```
git config --global user.signingkey <yourkey>
```

Read more here: https://help.github.com/en/articles/telling-git-about-your-signing-key