# How can I set up vscode to publish changes to git using gpg?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I get the error `gpg failed to sign the data` even though I've followed [this article](https://dev.to/devmount/signed-git-commits-in-vs-code-36do) and tried the steps from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0) but to no avail. Setting `git config --global gpg.program gpg2` yields the error `Cannot run gpg2: No such file or directory` even though I have the package installed.

I am using Linux and `vscode` through `flatpak`. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK Flatpak runs programs in separate containers. You have to allow it to access `gpg2` and perhaps other programs outside of VSCode container.

Comment: Thank you, @phd !! You should post this as an answer, because this was the issue.

Comment: I know very little about Flatpak. It would be better if **you** write the answer along with the commands to configure the container. I'll learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set read-only permissions to `flatpak` for it to read items from `/usr/bin/`  using `flatpak override --filesystem=host:ro`. But, in order not to make life hard for myself, I chose to install `vscode` from the official repos - which solved my issue without any hacky solutions.