# Error to commit changes from VS Code to GitHub

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

After I change some files on my local repository I want to commit these to my GitHub rep. Everytime this error shows up and I have no idea how to fix it. I tried to uninstall VSCode and Git on my PC, changes nothing.

error: cannot spawn gpg2: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

Comment: What exactly do you do? I don't think git tries to sign commits by default.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: you can run `git commit -s`, or set Git up to sign each commit. I wouldn't, for various reasons that include this kind of failure: the pain level is too high for the value received (though this is an opinion, not a fact).

Answer (score 0):

You chose to use `gpg2` to *sign* each commit.  Git itself never does any authentication, and simply *believes you* when you tell it that you are Fred Astaire, or Ginger Rogers, or whoever you wish to claim to be.

Some people object to this.  To help them out, Git offers the ability to run digital signature programs.  You can choose to:

- Sign *every single commit:* those who have access to digital signature verification software can then be assured that you are indeed Fred Rogers, or Ginger Astaire, or whomever.
- Sign *tags:* those who have access to digital signature verification software can then tell that you, whoever the signature verifies you to be, have agreed that this particular *tag* represents a good version of the software.

Because commits form a [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), signing a tag is "as good as" signing all the commits *leading up to the tag*.<sup>1</sup>

If you *do* choose to digitally sign each commit, or some tags, *you* must provide the digital signature software that will do this.  Git does not come with PGP or GPG.  They are pretty widely available though.  You may need to configure Git somewhat; see [gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object [Git 2.10.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39494631/1256452) for additional details.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, it's as good as the cryptographic hashes in the Merkle tree can verify.  Since Git's are a bit weak, this isn't as good as signing every commit.  However, the weaknesses in SHA-1, at least as they are known today, are not *that* large, so that any attack *on* the commit chain would be obvious.