# Why aren't my git commits able to be signed

Tags: git, git-commit

I am facing an issue with git commit. I don't know why it is not signing my commits

```
Lenovo@DESKTOP-ITBAPEA MINGW64 /d/drive d/web development/new web dev/doc/clone-krke-try (main)  
$ git config --global --list
user.name=name
user.email=email@gmail.com
user.signinkey=key
commit.gpgsign=true
tag.gpgsign=true
gpg.program=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuPG\\bin\\gpg.exe

Lenovo@DESKTOP-ITBAPEA MINGW64 /d/drive d/web development/new web dev/doc/clone-krke-try (main)  
$ git commit -m "new commit"
gpg: skipped "name <mailto:email@gmail.com>": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I don't know what the problem is.
I added GPG key to my github settings.

Comment: Are you using a private and not public key? Can you see your key if you run the following: gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long

Comment: Also you should never show real data, like your email and keys here in the examples, someone might exploit it ;)

Comment: I used this tutorial to setup signed commits. Use ssh-keys, they are easier to setup, and more secure. https://blog.artis3nal.com/blog/sign-commits-github-ssh/

Comment: Your problem has nothign to do with git hub, and we could honestly careless about what video you watched on youtube or how recent you watched it on youtube.  That doesn't tell you anything about it being correct or latest.   The problem is highlighted on your local machine.  If your commit is not signed with your GPG key then it will not show up as verified in ANY remote repository whether its GitHub or GitLab or anything.  You showed us your output that git commit is not able to sign with your key.  This is extremely common.

Comment: @kometen SSH Keys are not necessarily more secure or even as secure.  Very uninformed statement. Users can pick algo's which are quite insecure now in creating an SSH-KEY. Also SSH Keys can't be revoked. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/264365/what-are-the-security-implications-of-using-gpg-instead-of-ssh-keys-for-authenti details the differences better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object \[Git 2.10.0\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0)